# Installing TTF fonts in LaTeX

Tags: fonts, installing, truetype

One of the annoying aspects of LaTeX is the limited number of fonts that come by default, and the pain involved in making new fonts 'LaTeX' ready. I have a collection of truetype fonts that I'd like to prepare for use, and I definitely want to make sure I have vector versions of these fonts (i.e not type 3/bitmapped versions). Is there a relatively painless way to do this ?

Comment: Short answer: not really. I had to do it once 6 years ago to get some additional Chinese fonts working with CJKlatex, and all I can remember of that experience is that it was a complete pain and I would never, ever try to do that again.

Comment: @Willie: This is an example of the all-too-common [XY problem](http://www.perlmonks.org/index.pl?node_id=542341): the answer to "is there a painless way to generate latex font metrics from TTF fonts?" may well be "not really", but the XeLaTeX mention below *is* an answer to the question of "is there a painless way of using TTF fonts in a document?". :-)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: you are absolutely right. I didn't even consider the second option as being the question that was asked. My bad.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: exactly. It's not obvious from the question whether `latex` engine is a must, or any engine capable of processing LaTeX syntax is fit for the answer. Also it hasn't been specified which type of output is expected: dvi, ps, pdf, svg, or all of the above.

Comment: I'd prefer latex, and I want to generate dvi/ps/pdf.

Comment: There is a nice TUGboat article by S. Kroonenberg called "Font installation the shallow way"  <http://www.tug.org/TUGboat/Articles/tb27-1/tb86kroonenberg-fonts.pdf>. The article provides a number of examples of how to use different kinds of fonts with (pdf)LaTeX.

Comment: What I don't understand is why there isn't a script that just does it for you? That way only one person ever has to understand the convoluted process.

Comment: I've made the switch to xelatex, and am much happier :)

Comment: Still no way to do this (installing a `.TTF` font in LaTeX) in a **save and successful way**, in MiKTeX 2.9 (pdf)LaTeX???

Answer (score 35, accepted):

One solution is to use [XeLaTeX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XeTeX), which lets you use system fonts (mostly) hassle-free.

Comment: does that work in linux, and how does it help with installing fonts ?

Comment: XeLaTeX works on linux (and is probably installed already). It's a separate TeX engine, produces PDFs, and can use truetype fonts directly.

Comment: I helps with installaing fonts, since nothing special needs to be done at all to use an already available system ttf font.

Comment: That is the only viable solution now. It's 2011, we have XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX, and they work. So use them.

Answer (score 53):

The easiest way is with XeTeX or LuaTeX and the [`fontspec`](https://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package. They can use any TTF font installed on the system. For Linux this means both the system wide fonts and any fonts you put into `~/.fonts/` (e.g. by installing them via Nautilus).

To use the fonts you simply have to load the `fontspec` package and set the font:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Arial}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum...
\end{document}
```

Then compile the the document with `xelatex` or `lualatex`. The [`fontspec` documentation](https://texdoc.org/serve/fontspec.pdf/0) describes all the possibilities for changing fonts.

The only drawbacks (as far as I am aware) are that you can only generate .pdf files and that you need a sufficiently new TeX distribution (TeX Live 2009 should work for XeTeX and Tex Live 2010 for LuaTeX).

Comment: I use XeTeX myself and think it's a good solution.  There are some drawbacks, though, that may or may not be important to particular users.  One of the major drawbacks for some is that the microtype package for XeTeX is not fully functional; microtype with pdftex gives much better results.

Comment: this works (mostly) but I am finding that the TriniteNo2 font seems to have improper spacing in XeTeX for  "fi" and "fl" ... seems I need to place a space in there and then back up a little.  Otherwise, words like "fish" just have a curve followed by "sh"

Answer (score 25):

The process for PdfTeX is something like this (depends a little bit on your distribution):

1. Get autoinst.pl from Fontools from CPAN
2. Get otf2tfm from lcdf-typetools
3. Run autoinst.pl (using Perl) on all ttfs
4. Add generated PdfTeX font mapping (in MikTeX for instance [`initexmf --edit-config-file updmap`, add `Map yourmap.map` and run `initexmf --mkmaps`](http://docs.miktex.org/manual/advanced.html))

You can do the whole process manually as well (autoinst.pl is nothing but a smart wrapper):

1. Create tfm metrics and a ttfonts.map using `ttf2tfm`
2. Create virtual font tables using `vptovf`
3. Create afm metrics using `ttf2afm`
4. Create pdf font map using `afm2tfm`
5. Put *.tfm, *.afm, *.ttf, *.vf into the `fonts/tfm/` etc.
6. Add the font maps
7. Create a package/sty to pull the various fonts into a font family (this is where I am stuck)

My ruby script for running the commands looks like this:

```rb
require 'fileutils'  

basename = "Nexus"

open("#{basename}.map", 'a') { |pdfFontMap|

    Dir["#{basename}*.ttf"].each{ |file|

        file.sub!(/\.ttf$/, "")

        ttf = "#{file}.ttf"

        file.gsub!(/_/,"") # Remove underscores

        puts `ttf2tfm #{ttf} -q -T T1-WGL4.enc -v ec#{file}.vpl rec#{file}.tfm >> ttfonts.map`

        puts `vptovf ec#{file}.vpl ec#{file}.vf rec#{file}.tfm`

        puts `ttf2afm -e T1-WGL4.enc -o rec#{file}.afm #{ttf}`

        pdfFontMap.puts `afm2tfm rec#{file}.afm -T T1-WGL4.enc rec#{file}.tfm`.gsub(/\r|\n/, "") + " <#{ttf}"
    }
}
```

You can find more details about the manual way in:

http://www.radamir.com/tex/ttf-tex.htm

P.S.:

- Run `initexmf --update-fndb` EVERY time new files are put somewhere

Comment: I don't know if `initexmf` is an old invocation or a MiKTeX specific one but it is not something you should or could do in TeX Live at any time, let alone every time new files are put somewhere. Moreover, there is no required equivalent if you install into TEXMFHOME. Moreover describing this as 'the process for pdfTeX' is wrong. It is ***a*** process. It is not the only one. Also, I am pretty sure the manual process is mis-described. At the very least, it involves unnecessary steps.

Comment: Well cfr, the answer is 4 years old, so your mileage may vary and feel free to provide a better answer. Most of your comment does not provide any useful information for anybody.

Comment: Well it tells somebody running TeX Live that their system's failure to find `initexmf` is normal and does not mean their TeX installation is borked. It doesn't tell them what to do instead since that would take more than a comment. But it does tell them that they should look elsewhere for instructions. As I say, this command might have worked in past TeX Live installations or might be right for MiKTeX. But it isn't right for any relatively recent version of TeX Live. (In the strong sense that it isn't possible for relatively recent versions of TL.)

Answer (score 2):

LuaTeX brings TTF-support, but I have no Idea how mature it is right now.

Comment: It works. And it's not too difficult to use in ConTeXt. But I'm not sure if anyone exposed this functionality to LaTeX already.

Comment: The above example for xelatex (with fontspec + Arial) will work unchanged with lualatex too (with a recent fontspec). A discussion about difference of xelatex + lualatex is here http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/drawbacks-of-xetex-luatex