# Where to find nitty-gritty details about TeX and friends' font handling systems?

Tags: fonts, installing, opentype, truetype

The current guides online and in texdoc that I could find did not deal with the problem I have.

1. How to generate font metrics for system installed TrueType and OpenType fonts?
2. How to generate font maps? What is a difference between font maps for regular T1, TrueType and OpenType fonts?
3. Where to place those things and what "databases" do I need to update to make latex and friends "see" those fonts?
4. How to generate raster fonts for TrueType and OpenType fonts and how to install them?

The current documentation I could find didn't answer quickly and straight to the point about it. I don't want "programmers" guide to fonts. I want "user's and packaging" guide to fonts. Please point to existing resource or provided references to pages / section from texdoc.

**EDIT**

Dead-end or not deadend, in the end of the day I need to generate PDF/A documents with embedded metadata. The PDF/A metadata is only possible with pdfTeX engine and pdf-x package. And I want embedded custom ttf fonts in those PDF/A documents.

Comment: Just some pedantry: can you fix the two obvious typos in the title? There should be an apostrophe after friends and a 'd' in handling. Thanks. Oh, and good question, btw. Once upon a time I found some guide and followed it. But I haven't been able to find it again. So I'm curious as to the answer too.

Comment: this seems to relate to http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226/installing-ttf-fonts-in-latex

Comment: @Suresh: Yes it does. That questions says "use XeLaTeX" =) but I really really want to use pdfTeX engine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think one of the issues here is that font installation is *very* complicated, and so there is only really a 'programmers' solution. (That is to say there is no simple answer, so you have to be prepared to learn a lot of low-level stuff to get it to work.) One of the clearest descriptions, at least for Type 1 fonts, is [written by Lehmann](http://mirror.ctan.org/info/Type1fonts/fontinstallationguide/fontinstallationguide.pdf). Other than that, I'm afraid you have to read the [`fontinst` stuff](http://tug.org/applications/fontinst/), but from your question I guess you already have and found it to be wanting.

Comment: I'm Ubuntu developer and have access to the new Ubuntu TTF font. And I really want to package it with latex-ready fonts such that when it goes public everyone and me including can use it with latex (any type/engine). Type1 fonts are easy, and those generally already come repackaged for latex, I did read both of these font guides, and yes they weren't a helpful tutorial for *distribution* packager to package ttf font from source for latex.

Comment: Anything to be packaged needs to go to CTAN, so the TeX Live and MiKTeX people, surely.

Comment: Obviously, but when the font is publicly released in october.

Answer (score 2):

Use LuaTeX + luaotfload + fontspec. Don't waste your time trying to learn a dead end technology. I have been doing a lot of font installation (also for money). This is awful.

Comment: Or XeLaTeX plus fontspec, for the same general reasons.

Comment: @Joseph The author states "but I really really want to use pdfTeX engine", and LuaTeX comes close. For most purposes (98%) XeLaTeX is suitable as well.

Comment: Sorry, must have missed that. I was simply noting, as you say, that for most purposes XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX have a lot of 'overlap'.

Comment: Can I embed PDF/A metadata streams in the pdf similar to what pdfTeX engine does?

Comment: Yes, you should be able to do that, because LuaTeX is an enhanced PDFTeX engine. I don't know the commands you should use, though.

Answer (score 0):

simplefonts module provides fontspec-like functionality in ConTeXt (MkIV).