# Is there a simple way to use the gentium font in latex?

Tags: fonts, packages, pdftex, xetex

I'd like to use the [gentium](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gentium) font in a LaTeX document, and the instructions I found 
[at this site](http://tclab.kaist.ac.kr/ipe/pdftex_3.html) make it look rather difficult.

Is there a simple package that is now available that would allow me to use the gentium font more easily?

Comment: One simple solution is to use XeLaTeX, which can use any system fonts. :-) See [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226/installing-ttf-fonts-in-latex).

Comment: This question should imho be tagged with specific engines if there is an answer for them.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR, I did manage to get it to work with XeLaTeX in the end. Could you post that as an answer (with a simple working example) so I can accept it?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Posting the XeLaTeX comment as an answer, per suggestion. You just  `\setromanfont{Gentium}`.

Note that the font Gentium [doesn't yet](http://scripts.sil.org/cms/scripts/page.php?site_id=nrsi&item_id=Gentium_status) have a bold variant, so if you need to use **bold** frequently, it's recommended that you use a different font. (If your interest in Gentium is because of its wide character repertoire, you may want to use a font like Charis SIL. If your interest was in the appearance, then there's a "Gentium Basic" that doesn't include Greek or Cyrillic characters, but has bold variants.) But in practice I found I could use Gentium with Gentium Basic Bold as the bold font, and it looks natural to my eyes (you still won't have bold Greek, of course):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setromanfont[BoldFont={Gentium Basic Bold},ItalicFont={Gentium Italic}]{Gentium}

\begin{document}
Look:\\
Hèllö wőrld: γεντιυμ \textit{Italic} \textbf{Bold}\\
\textbf{Hèllö wőrld}: γεντιυμ \textit{Italic} Bold
\end{document}
```

Comment: Should this now be `\setmainfont`?

Comment: @cfr It's been a while since I used it, but the fontspec doc (fontspec.pdf) says that `\setromanfont` is "the old name for `\setmainfont`, retained for backwards compatibility" — so yes `\setmainfont` is the new name, but `\setromanfont` is also a (deprecated) synonym and should work I think.

Comment: Thanks. I should have just said 'Is this the same as...?' which was what I was really wondering.

Comment: For Lualatex, I had to had the arguments `Renderer=Basic,Ligatures=TeX`. Otherwise ligatures like `--` did not work (using Texlive 2015).

Answer (score 9):

Now there is a [gentium-tug](http://ctan.org/pkg/gentium-tug) package that enables you to

```
\usepackage{gentium}
```

No additional steps required.

Answer (score 8):

If you want to use pdfLaTeX, you can use the [autoinst](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/utilities/fontools/) tool.

```
cd ${YOUR_TEX_DOCUMENT_DIR}
autoinst ${PATH_TO_GENTIUM}/Gen*.ttf
```

This will convert the ttf files and create a Gentium.sty file in the current directory. Now you can simply

```
\usepackage{Gentium}
```

to switch your LaTeX font to Gentium. Alternatively, try GentiumBasic for **bold**.

Answer (score 3):

The [`gentium`](http://ctan.org/pkg/gentium) package found on CTAN may help get you started with using Gentium in pdfLaTeX.

Comment: Sadly this doesn't seem to work for me. After installing it I included \usepackage{gentium} and received "LaTeX Error: File `gentium.sty' not found.".

Not sure if this is relevant: "Other encodings, and LaTeX support remain to be added." (from the linked page on CTAN).

Comment: Working for me. Maybe that @bryn needs to install the package.

Answer (score 1):

While the XeLaTeX way is probably easier, if you wanted to stick with pdflatex, you could try the [fontinst](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontinst) tool for creating the necessary package.

Comment: Just tried this using the autoinst script from the fontools package on CTAN and now have Gentium working with pdflatex.