# winfonts problem

Tags: fonts, led-editor

I'm using Led editor in Windows 7. I want to use Times font but the output pdf fonts are somewhat different.

Here are the codes for Times font

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{winfonts}
\fontfamily{times-ttf}\selectfont 
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{times-ttf}
  \renewcommand{\rmdefault}{times-ttf}
  \renewcommand{\sfdefault}{times-ttf}
\renewcommand*\familydefault{\ttdefault}
```

and I copy the `winfonts.sty` in the same directory. What may cause this problem or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: why don't you simply use `\usepackage{mathptmx}` or `\usepackage{times}`?

Comment: Copying `winfonts.sty` is not enough. What have you done with the other files? And did you add `\pdfmapfile{=winfonts.map}` to your document?

Answer (score 2):

Copying the `.sty` file is not enough to install this package. You should follow the steps described in the package [README](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/winfonts/README) file.

If you only need a font that *looks* like Times, consider using

```
\usepackage{mathptmx}
```

The `times` package is deprecated and should not be used.

Another way to get the real Times New Roman font is to use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX with the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Times New Roman}

\begin{document}

Hello World

\end{document}
```

(Compile with `xelatex` or `lualatex`. If you choose this route, see [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/36/differences-between-luatex-context-and-xetex) or [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3094/drawbacks-of-xetex-luatex) question for a start.)

Comment: `times` is deprecated if you want to use math fonts, too.

Comment: @Herbert: Well, the [CTAN page](http://ctan.org/pkg/times) for `times` says so. Not that anything relevant is mentioned in `psnfss` documentation.