# enpassant chess font

Tags: chessboard

I have got a ttf-font that I will like to use in chess diagrams. I have installed in the enpassant package before, but this time I only have the ttf-file. How do I convert this into the LaTeX package?

Comment: If you're trying to install a `.ttf` font in LaTeX, perhaps [Installing TTF fonts in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226/installing-ttf-fonts-in-latex) would help.

Comment: Instruction how I converted the fonts are in the documentation of chessfss. (Nowadays I would suggest to use fontforge to generate the pfb + tfm).