# How do I use custom fonts?

Tags: fonts, packages

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Installing TTF fonts in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226/installing-ttf-fonts-in-latex)

I have some fonts I bought a while ago I wish to use in some Latex documents. Can I use them in Latex and if so, how?  Please note I am new to Latex so will need any answers to be explicit (sorry in advance).

Comment: In what format are those fonts?

Comment: Since you mention that you purchased the fonts, they're probably in TrueType or OpenType format. If that's the case, you may want to switch from pdflatex to either xelatex or lualatex, as the latter two can work directly with fonts in `.ttf` and `.otf` format.