# autoinst -- cannot use truetype font

Tags: fonts, pdftex, truetype

I'm trying to use the `DroidSans` font in a deck of slides I'm making with `Beamer`. 
I got the truetype file for this font, that is `DroidSans-webfont.ttf`, hence I executed, in my working directory:

```
$ autoinst DroidSans-webfont.ttf
```

This generated three files, specifically:

```
DroidSans.map
DroidSans.sty
LY1DroidSans-TLF.fd
```

Then, I included the following command in my .tex source file

```
\usepackage{DroidSans}
```

and compiled the source with `pdflatex`. Compilation fails, reporting this error:

```
kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 --mag 0+300/600 --dpi 300 DroidSans-tlf-ly1--base
mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for DroidSans-tlf-ly1--base.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file DroidSans-tlf-ly1--base): Font DroidSans-tlf-ly1--base at 300 not found
==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
```

What's going on here? Am I missing something?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.sx!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/19384) Truetype is not easily accommodated in LaTeX. You could look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226/19384 for some different solutions.

Comment: You could use the `droidsans` package: [Droid Sans in The LaTeX Font Cataloque](http://www.tug.dk/FontCatalogue/droidsans/).

Comment: I tried using the `droidsans` package, still I got a similar error:

`kpathsea: Running mktexpk --mfmode / --bdpi 600 -mag 0+360/600 --dpi 360 DroidSans-03
    mktexpk: don't know how to create bitmap font for DroidSans-03.
    kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.
    (see the transcript file for additional information)
    !pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file DroidSans-03): Font DroidSans-03 at 360 not found`

Comment: @LorisFichera: have you (re)moved your generated files?

Comment: @Silex: yes, I did.

Comment: @LorisFichera: What OS and LaTeX distribution do you use?

Comment: I'm currently using Ubuntu 12.04 with texlive.
I manually installed the `DroidSans` package, downloading it from CTAN, as you pointed me.

Comment: @LorisFichera: Can you upgrade to TeX Live 2012? See: [How do I install the latest TeX Live 2012?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/163682/how-do-i-install-the-latest-tex-live-2012) It probably contains a properly installed version of the `droidsans` package.

Comment: @silex: oh, thank you for sharing this. I did not know there was a way to install a newer texlive-extra-fonts package on ubuntu 10.04!

Comment: @PeterJansson: He uses pdfTeX, which can handle TrueType fonts. This should work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to activate the map-file, either globally with `updmap-sys` (or `updmap`) or by using `\pdfmapfile{=DroidSans.map}` in your document.