# Adding an image on either side of the page number

Tags: graphics

[image]

I want to use this image together with the page number that is in the bottom of the page; one image in each side of the page number for all the pages. Can someone show me how to do it?

Maybe this image will make it clear:

[image]

Comment: Please rewrite your question. At the moment it is not clear what you want. Really. For example, what is an "hte page number"?

Comment: I edited it i hope it's clear now

Comment: BTW, there is probably (I haven't understood the question yet) no need for an image: `\usepackage{pifont}` provides the symbol as `\ding{63}`.

Comment: Do you know the number in the bottom of the pages in books?This is what I want but I want it to have more them just the number of the page, i want it to have a image at each side of the number.I'm struggling because english is not my first language feel free to ask

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

## The symbols as part of the page number

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{pifont}

\renewcommand*{\thepage}{\ding{63}\arabic{page}\ding{63}}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Lorem ipsum}
\label{lorem}
\lipsum[1]
This is page \pageref{lorem}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with the symbols as part of the page number]

## The symbols only appear in the footer

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{pifont}% Provides \ding

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{\ding{63}\thepage\ding{63}}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Lorem ipsum}
\label{lorem}
\lipsum[2]
This is page \pageref{lorem}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with symbols in footer only]

### Variation with larger symbols

```
\documentclass[a5paper]{article}
\usepackage[pass]{geometry}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage{pifont}% Provides \ding

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\fancyhead{} % clear all header fields
\fancyfoot{} % clear all footer fields
\fancyfoot[C]{%
  {\large\ding{63}}%
  \,%
  \textbf{\thepage}%
  \,%
  {\large\ding{63}}%
}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\renewcommand{\footrulewidth}{0pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\section{Lorem ipsum}
\label{lorem}
\lipsum[2]
This is page \pageref{lorem}.
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with enlarged symbols]

## Font Alice-Regular with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX

Starting point for using a font with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX.
The font setup for non-Unicode TeX compiler (pdfTeX, TeX) are much
more complicate, because font metrics need to be generated and used.

The font file `Alice-Regular.ttf` can be put in the working directory or installed in the home or local TDS (texmf) tree below `TDS:fonts/truetype//`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\FontAlice{Alice-Regular.ttf}
\begin{document}
\ding{63}\,{\FontAlice\thepage}\,\ding{63}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Page number with font Alice-Regular]

### Scaled version

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontface\FontAlice{Alice-Regular.ttf}
\begin{document}
\begingroup
  \sbox{0}{\ding{63}}%
  \usebox{0}\,%
  \resizebox{!}{\ht0}{\FontAlice\thepage}\,%
  \usebox{0}%
\endgroup
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result with scaled page number]

Comment: Thanks it worked, just one more thing how I edit the font for the number?

Comment: @AdrielCarlos With the appropriate font switching command. In the image of the question, the font seems to be the same (or similar) to the font used in the title. But I do not know, which font you want to use.

Comment: I'm thinking in using this font: http://www.1001freefonts.com/alice.font if you could help in using it in both title and number.

Comment: @AdrielCarlos I have updated the answer for a short example, how the font can be used with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX. However, font installation leads too much away from the question. The same holds for changing title fonts. This belongs to a different question with much more details, like which kind of title (document, section, ...), relation to the body fonts, ... Also, Alice-Regular does not seem to have a bold companion, which is often used in titles.

Comment: I'm using pdflatex, and I know that what I'm asking go beyond and I asked it in other place but you are awnsering and in the other post nobody is.Also how I enlarge the font size so that it get the same size that the images?

Comment: @AdrielCarlos If you want to use fonts from the non-TeX world, it is will be much easier to use LuaLaTeX. Otherwise, see [Installing TTF fonts in LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/226/16967).

Comment: Ok I see your point, so what font do you recoemnd for me to use in pdflatex?