# Missing letters in calligra font

Tags: accents, characters, calligra

I'd like to use calligra font for a cite, but two letters are missing from the package: ő and ű. The code:

```
\documentclass[xetex]{beamer}
\usepackage{calligra}
\usepackage[magyar]{babel}

\usetheme{metropolis}

\title{Oszthatóság, az oszthatóság tulajdonságai}
\subtitle{Algebra és számelmélet}
\author{Benkó Tamás}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \begin{center}
    \vfill
    \Huge\calligra Isten a számokban rejtőzik, a szám a szépség másik 
neve.
  \end{center}
  \hfill Dimitri Verhulst
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I use XeLaTeX, as it seen in the document class options, but I don't think it is part of the problem. Is there a way to have those two letters in the font?

Comment: The calligra package should not be used with xelatex, it uses an unsuitable font encoding.

Comment: The font doesn't have the double acute accent.

Comment: Okay, then what font should I use? I would at least trying all found fonts one by one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't the `.ttf` or `.otf` file of your font in your computer, download it from the Internet.

When you already have your font, use it in LaTeX by the `fontspec` package and the `\setmainfont` command:

```
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{calligra.ttf}
% if your file is named calligra.ttf
```

Doing in this way you can use any font you want in your LaTeX document, not just Calligra.

**Read more:** [Installing TTF fonts in LaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226/installing-ttf-fonts-in-latex).

Hope this will help!

**Edit** If you just want to use the font locally, try this code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\hello{calligra.ttf} 
    % Define new font family to use it locally in a part of the document
\begin{document}
This is a \hello{meaningless} sentence to check.
\end{document}
```

Comment: That's okay, when I want to use in the whole document. But I'd like to use it just for one sentence.

Comment: @ThomasBenko I have edited my answer.

Comment: Tnx, it helped!