# Font Choice and Classic Thesis

Tags: fonts, typography, classicthesis

I don't own the Minion Pro font, so that's not an option for me. But I do have Adobe Caslon Pro, which is a serif font I'm fond of.

Is it possible to use the classicthesis.sty and use Caslon Pro instead? I can't see a way currently to do this.

As a second option, I like how Palatino looks from the `mathpazo` package, but I prefer the Computer Modern Serif maths typesetting. Is it possible to have the body text in Palatino while having the maths written in Computer Modern Serif?

Comment: Welcome ! With latex you can easily have two different font settings for text and math contents so I guess the answer to your last question is yes. If you want to check other fonts have a look at the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/), there is a [Libre Caslon](https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/librecaslon/) font listed

Comment: Thanks for the links @BambOo

Can you help with the syntax to change the font of the maths (inline and block) only? I cant find anything with my weak google-fu

Comment: Well, you just have to load a math font package such as `\usepackage{mathptmx}`

Comment: Right, but when I load `mathpazo` with `\usepackage{mathptmx}`, it changes the body text too. 

If I wanted to use palatino font, with the default maths typesetting, do I not use `mathpazo`, but some other package?

Comment: Both `mathpazo` and `mathptmx` actually set both math and text fonts, bu you can try loading e.g. `mathptmx` then `charter` for instance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no real problem in using different fonts with `classicthesis`. Just load the related font package and you're done.

Compile with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX

```latex
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{classicthesis}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\setmainfont{BaskervilleF}

\renewcommand{\chapterNumber}{\fontsize{70}{0}\addfontfeatures{Numbers=OldStyle}}

\begin{document}

\frontmatter

\tableofcontents

\mainmatter

\chapter{Introduction}

\lipsum

\end{document}
```

I don't own Adobe Caslon Pro, so I used a different font. The only adjustment is to make `\chapterNumber` aware of the text font, otherwise it would use Palatino.

[image]

Comment: Compiling with `XeLaTeX` would be best - i get a bunch of errors, but maybe I can squash all of those - thank you!

Comment: @GiacomoPope Be warned that text in Adobe Caslon and math in Computer Modern (or PaZo) is a punch in the eye. If you plan to use math in your thesis, use a text font that has a companion math font.

Comment: Yeah, I was hoping to do a new font which is nicer for reading, but I'm hot happy with any math font other than the standard (too many years of conditioning?)

Starting to think that computer modern for the whole document is probably the best idea.

Answer (score 1):

Not really an answer, but this way I can show some output of computer modern math with `librecaslon` font

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{librecaslon}
\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

[image]

**EDIT**
and now with Palatino text font

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\blindmathpaper
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So here you load in 
```
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{librecaslon}
```

And `\usepackage{lmodern}` sets the font for the whole document, then `\usepackage{librecaslon}` sets the font for everything it can, which doesn't include maths, so it only affects the body text?

I could do this with Palatino if I could find Palatino in a package that isn't `mathpazo` ?

Comment: @GiacomoPope yes that's pretty much what happens. It seems that to load only the `palatino` font for text you have to load `newpxtext` instead

Comment: Thanks @BambOo, that's looking great. 

Is using a custom font important from a ttf, otf file possible for `pdfLatex`? I know you can with `XeLaTeX`, but that's not compatible with `classicthesis`

Comment: You can achieve it with `lualatex` see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226/installing-ttf-fonts-in-latex . Any specific reason for choosing `classicthesis` ?

Comment: It seemed like a nice starting point for a thesis formatting. Is there something you would recommend beyond that for a PhD thesis?

Comment: I personally used `yathesis` as I am french but the documentation only comes in french, so it's probably not a good option for you

Comment: @GiacomoPope Classicthesis works with xelatex as it does with pdflatex and lualatex. There may be issues with clashing versions of loaded packages.

Comment: @PhilipPirrip yes, i managed to find a way to maybe xelatex, just needed to turn off some settings that were clearly highlighted for pdflatex. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

This is from the "some kind of manual" that comes with classicthesis (LyX version):
XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX make the use of Unicode fonts possible through the package fontspec. The global font options set by classicthesis.sty are:

```
\setmainfont{TeX Gyre Pagella}
\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}
\setmonofont{Liberation Mono}
```

Pretty much any other font can be used by issuing these commands after the classicthesis style has been loaded.