# How to use Johnston Sans or an equivalent substitute?

Tags: fonts

I'd like to use [Johnston Sans](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnston_(typeface)) font.
Apparently, [its licensing is strictly controlled](https://tfl.gov.uk/info-for/suppliers-and-contractors/font-requests).

On the [LaTeX Font Catalogue](https://www.tug.org/FontCatalogue/sansseriffonts.html) I didn't find any free substitute.

Is it possible to have it working in {pdf,Xe,Lua}LaTeX in any way?

Comment: Without applying for a license, I can’t know what the obstacles are.  But (unless you need an italic) I’d recommend [P22 Underground](https://p22.com/family-Underground) and its [engraved version](https://p22.com/family-Underground_Engraved).  I’ve used them with `fontspec` and `luatex` and had no problem whatsoever.

Comment: There are also free — but much more limited — versions by [Nick Curtis](https://www.1001fonts.com/underground-font.html) and [GregF](https://www.1001fonts.com/railway-font.html).  One of these may suffice for your project.

Comment: thanks! can you give me some directions on how to use them?
I guess that this is a starting point: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/226/installing-ttf-fonts-in-latex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest and most powerful way to use the fonts which interest you is with `fontspec` in `luatex` (or `xetex`, though you miss out on the possibilities of `\directlua{...}` in that case).

Here is an example of using P22 Underground Pro:

```
\documentclass[14pt]{beamer}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setsansfont{P22 Underground Pro Book}[
  Numbers=OldStyle]
\newfontface\engraved{P22 Underground Engraved}
\linespread{1.104}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
  \frametitle{\engraved P22 Underground Pro}

  P22 Underground Pro supports Latin (with all characters needed for
  transliteration of Semitic languages), Greek (including polytonic
  Greek), and Cyrillic. There are arrows, circled numbers, and useful
  dingbats.

  \bigskip

  \addfontfeatures{StylisticSet={3,7}}
  I’m fond of the humanistic alternates (Q W g) and the diamond
  points (:).
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

The free versions of this typeface which I noted in the comments don't have stylistic sets, contextual alternates, or other special features, so a simple `\setsansfont{Underground NF}` or `\setsansfont{Railway}` should do the trick.

Comment: Always thank you for all....

Comment: and the font file goes in `texmf` or in the document root directory, does it?

Comment: It can go in the document directory (in that case, you invoke it by file name), or wherever your operating system wants fonts installed (for me, on GNU/Linux, that's the `.fonts` in my home directory).