# Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX

Tags: packages, pdftex, xetex

Until now, I have been compiling my LaTeX documents with pdfLaTeX. My standard document preamble includes the "usual suspects" for non-English speakers ([`inputenc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc), [`fontenc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc), [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel)) and a bunch of other packages. Assuming I were to convert to XeLaTeX, what modifications of my preamble are advisable? I'm aware that the `expansion=true` option of the [`microtype`](http://ctan.org/pkg/microtype) package is not (yet) available for XeLaTeX, and that [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) is sort of a default package for OpenType fonts. What other packages (and package options) should be removed and, vice versa, incorporated when switching from pdfLaTeX to XeLaTeX?

Comment: Related question -- the same for LuaLaTeX: [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and LuaLaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/28642)

Answer (score 142, accepted):

- Don't load [`inputenc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/inputenc) or [`fontenc`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontenc) manually; use UTF-8 input and the [`fontspec`](http://ctan.org/pkg/fontspec) package instead
- Don't load the [`textcomp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) package; if you want macros to enter varios symbols, load the [`xunicode`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xunicode) package (EDIT BY LOCKSTEP: [According to  Ulrike Fischer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/78767/510), *"[i]n a current system you don't need to load `xunicode` at all, `fontspec` will do it at the correct place"*)
- Use [`polyglossia`](http://ctan.org/pkg/polyglossia) instead of [`babel`](http://ctan.org/pkg/babel)
- For OpenType math support, use [`unicode-math`](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode-math) instead of [`amsfonts`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsfonts)/`amssymb` etc. (but [`amsmath`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amsmath) can/should still be used).
- The [`xltxtra`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xltxtra) package isn't necessary any more

Everything in this list is probably valid for LuaLaTeX, too, with the exception of `xunicode`, which requires XeTeX.

Comment: I've noticed the `xltxtra` package - is this essential or only "nice to have"?

Comment: **@lockstep**: nowadays (TL2010) xltxtra isn't really necessary at all; all of its essential components have been incorporated into fontspec.

Comment: What about the `textcomp` package - is this redundant/wrong when using XeLaTeX?

Comment: The `textcomp` package provides access to symbols from the TS1 encoding. In XeLaTeX, these can be directly entered or accessed via the macros from the `xunicode` package. So I'd say that `textcomp` is wrong and should be left out or replaced by `xunicode`.

Comment: I've always found fontenc to be useful.

Comment: `fontenc` can be used for Type1 fonts in old font encoding. In fact `fontspec` itself loads `fontenc` and set `EU1` as default encoding. It's OK to use more font encodings like `T1`, `LY1`, etc.

Comment: `amssymb` and other math font packages can still be used. In fact, usually we still use Type1 fonts without `unicode-math`, e.g. Latin Modern by default. And font packages like `euler`, `txfonts`, `cmbright`, `mathdesign` ... are still very useful when using XeTeX. There are only very few OpenType math fonts, AFAIK only 4 are free: LM, Asana, XITS, Euler.

Comment: @Leo: I've made the suggestions a bit more detailed.

Comment: What is the replacement for babel/polyglossia when using LuaLaTeX?

Comment: @JLDiaz : the latest versions of polyglossia (1.3.x May 2013) are compatible with LuaLaTeX. They are included in TexLive 2013 (currently under test).

Answer (score 55):

Trying to implement all the answers and comments given in this thread 
using the [`ifxetex`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/ifxetex) package, 
I ended up with the following code for my preamble. 
It allows to switch forth and back anytime between `pdflatex` and `xelatex` as compiler.
Note: When switching the compiler, one should delete the `.aux` files.

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    ngerman
]{scrbook}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{ifxetex}
\ifxetex
    % XeLaTeX
    \usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setmainlanguage[spelling=new,babelshorthands=true]{german}
    \usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage[]{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont{XITS}
    \setmathfont{XITS Math}
\else
    % default: pdfLaTeX
    \usepackage{babel}
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
    %\usepackage{lmodern}
    \usepackage[adobe-utopia]{mathdesign}
    \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
    \usepackage[babel=true]{microtype}
\fi

% some more packages like csquotes, biblatex, hyperref

\begin{document}
...
\end{document}
```

I had to load the `amsmath` package before the XeLaTeX `setmathfont` command to avoid the error `\dddot already defined.`
With MiKTeX 2.9 one has to manually install the XITS fonts using the MiKTeX package manager.

Comment: Since `polyglossia-1.2` you need to set the language explicitly with `\setmainlanguage` instead of relying on the class/package-option.

Comment: @canaaerus Thanks, now setting the main ployglossia language explicitly.

Answer (score 34):

Apart from the packages you mentioned, the only difference that I have is that I don’t load the `inputenc` package and don’t set a font encoding.

Furthermore, you should remove any explicit driver names if you have given them in options to packages (e.g. `hyperref` or `xcolor`). These driver names are wrong at worst and redundant at best, since the packages do find the correct driver automatically when loaded within `xelatex`.

Comment: Thanks for reminding me that package options may also have to be modified - I've edited my question accordingly. Regarding driver name options, my understanding is that they are "bad practice" in both pfdLateX and XeLaTeX.

Comment: @lockstep: yes, they are. But I distinctly remember that a few years ago I needed them to get things to work. Not sure if that was my own incompetence or if the packages have gotten better at recognizing the processor.

Comment: Driver options are required if and only if you want to post-process a DVI file with something other than `dvips` (e.g., `dvipdfmx`).