# How do I typeset arbitrary fractions like the standard symbol for .5 = ½?

Tags: fractions

I know I've seen somewhere how to typeset 1/2 as ½, but with arbitrary fractions (that is, a macro that takes two arguments and makes the first denominator and the second numerator...). Now I can't seem to find it.

**How do I typeset an arbitrary fraction the same way as ½?**

Comment: There is a simple plain tex solution too. See my answer below

Answer (score 121, accepted):

You want [`xfrac`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xfrac)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\begin{document}
\sfrac{12}{3}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

There are differences between `xfrac` and `nicefrac` (detailed in the manual for `xfrac`), particularly if you are using fonts other than Computer Modern.

Comment: Thanks. I still use `nicefrac` today ... I should stop doing that!

Comment: Note that `\sfrac` looks nice only in normal text, not in math mode (at least in my case it is like that).

Comment: Unfortunately, `sfrac`, `xfrac`, `nicefrac` do not work with MathJax.

Comment: This is an alternative (if you depend on Mathjax): https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/251123/63540

Answer (score 38):

If you're using XeTeX or LuaTeX with `fontspec`, you might be using a font that has the OpenType feature `frac`, which might either be limited to a certain number of fixed fractions (e.g. [Junicode](http://junicode.sourceforge.net/)), or it works with any combination of digits, e.g. in Linux Libertine ([`libertineotf`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/libertineotf) package) or [EB Garamond](http://www.georgduffner.at/ebgaramond/).

Here's a MWE using `libertineotf`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \usepackage{libertineotf}
\begin{document}
\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+frac}

1/2 3/4 5/6 7/8 9/10 11/12 31415/27182 1000/1000000

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

If the font contains the OpenType features `numr` (numerator) and `dnom` (denominator), we can get even fancier and typically include a greater variety of glyphs:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
    \setmainfont{EB Garamond 12 Regular}

\newcommand{\unifrac}[2]{\mbox{% making sure we don't get a line break
    {\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+numr}#1}%
    ⁄% That slash is U+2044 FRACTION SLASH, which has special spacing
    {\addfontfeatures{RawFeature=+dnom}#2}%
    }}

\begin{document}

\unifrac{12}{14} \unifrac{31415}{27182} \unifrac{abc}{def} \unifrac{Foo!}{Bar?}
\unifrac{\#\$\%+/<>=}{?\@[]\textbackslash\_|\{\}§†}

\end{document}
```

[image: output]

To find out which features your OpenType font has, see

- [How do I get a list of all font features supported by current font](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/25924/4012).

To find our which fractions are included e.g. in Junicode's `frac` feature, see

- [How to find out which glyphs are different in an OpenType style set?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/75720/4012).

To get started with Xe(La)TeX and/or Lua(La)TeX, see

- [Frequently loaded packages: Differences between pdfLaTeX and XeLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/2984/4012) and
- [How do I use a particular font for a small section of text in my document? ⇒ XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/37251/4012)

Comment: I wish I could favourite this answer because it a) has a great new command, and b) provides great resources as well. 10/10, would upvote again

Comment: Can you still get this with LuaLaTeX (as opposed to XeLaTeX)?

Answer (score 27):

Perhaps [`nicefrac`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/nicefrac) is something you want to use?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicefrac}
\begin{document}
\nicefrac{12}{3}
\end{document}
```

[image: output]

Comment: Apparently, nicefrac works well for Computer Modern but not for other fonts (according to the xfrac documentation).

Answer (score 23):

A simple plain TeX construct produces very nice results too:

```
${}^1{\mskip -5mu/\mskip -3mu}_2$
```

[image: rendered]

Comment: Nice! It also works with fraction over fraction, a bit small though, but good enough. See [example](https://www.matheretter.de/rechner/latex/?tex=%7B%7D%5E%7B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bg(x)%7D%7B%5Cmskip%20-5mu%2F%5Cmskip%20-3mu%7D_%7B%20%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bf(x)%7D%20%7D%7D%0A)

Comment: Yes that's a bit small, but of course 1/g(x) / 1/f(x) should be written as f(x)/g(x) ;)

Comment: BTW: keeping the example in plain TeXnique I would prefer {1 \over g(x)} over \frac{1}{g(x)}

Comment: This is great. If your compiler can handle unicode correctly (which I think means you're using XeTeX or LuaTeX, but not sure), the Fraction Slash character `⁄` (U+2044) is even better than an ordinary slash.

Answer (score 8):

(*As there is always a solution using TikZ, it is here!*)

This solution automates the usage of `\frac`, a modified version of `\slantfrac`, or `\sfrac`.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{fpu}
\usepackage{fp}
\usepackage{parskip}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\pagestyle{empty}
\begin{document}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/frac}
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.333333333333333}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.5}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{2.133333333333325e-01}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.12}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{2.666666666666646e-02}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{-1.333333333333334e-02}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{7.200000000000000e-01}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{6.666666666666667e-02}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{1.333333333333333e-01}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{-1.333333333333333e-02}\hspace{1em}

\newcommand{\slantfrac}[2]{\,^{#1}\!/_{#2}}
\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/frac TeX={\slantfrac}}
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.333333333333333}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.5}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{2.133333333333325e-01}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.12}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{2.666666666666646e-02}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{-1.333333333333334e-02}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{7.200000000000000e-01}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{6.666666666666667e-02}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{1.333333333333333e-01}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{-1.333333333333333e-02}\hspace{1em}

\pgfkeys{/pgf/number format/frac TeX={\sfrac}}
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.333333333333333}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.5}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{2.133333333333325e-01}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{0.12}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{2.666666666666646e-02}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{-1.333333333333334e-02}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{7.200000000000000e-01}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{6.666666666666667e-02}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{1.333333333333333e-01}\hspace{1em}
\pgfmathprintnumber{-1.333333333333333e-02}\hspace{1em}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

`\textfrac{1}{2}` from Todd Lehman, [Improved kerning in fractions?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/43119/6865), might be another alternative for you. You can also find a graphical comparison of `\nicefrac` and `\sfrac` there.

Answer (score 4):

You can actually make your own pretty easily by using superscripts and subscripts:
this would be a/b:

```
$\,^{a}\!/\!_{b}$
```

I use the following command to make it easier to use more than once:

```
\newcommand{\slantfrac}[2]{\,^{#1}\!/\!_{#2}}
```

Comment: Without having checked, I suspect that this doesn't look as nice as \xfrac or \nicefrac, as it does nothing about kerning.

Comment: @lee I have used `^1/_2`; what do the other symbols do?

Comment: What about `\slantfrac{1}{10}`?