# How to print \frac{1}{2} by a single Unicode character?

Tags: math-mode, symbols, fontspec, unicode-math, fractions

I am looking for a command which would print simple fractions like 1/2, 1/3 etc using glyphs available in modern TTF/OTF fonts. Ideally, I want this command to output ordinary `\frac{1}{2}`, `\frac{1}{3}` in case if my document is compiled with (PDF)LaTeX, but outputs something like `$\text{\char"00BD}$` in case if the compiler is XeLaTeX of LuaLaTeX (and `fontspec` and / or `unicode-math` is loaded) and required Unicode character is available in current font.

Is such a command already invented by somebody?

Comment: The [`xfrac`](http://ctan.org/pkg/xfrac) package typesets "text" style fractions. It does not use complete Unicode characters, but, because of that, is able to handle arbitrary numerator and denominator values.

Comment: If you are using an editor that supports Unicode you might like to look at the `newunicodechar` package: this supports XeLaTeX, LuaLaTeX or (pdf)LaTeX (using the `inputenc` package along with the `utf8` option).

Comment: @mas: Unfortunately, WinEdt does not support unicode at such a level. It seems to convert UTF8 encoded files to ANSI at read|write stage.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You might try

```
\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage{ifxetex,ifluatex}

\newif\ifunicode
\ifxetex\unicodetrue\else\ifluatex\unicodetrue\fi\fi 

\ifunicode
  \usepackage{unicode-math}
  \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,Fractions=On]{XITS}
  \setmathfont{XITS Math}

  \makeatletter
  \let\@@@frac\frac
  \def\frac#1#2{\sbox0{#1/#2}\sbox2{#1\phantom{/}#2}%
    \ifdim\wd0=\wd2 % no corresponding character
      \@@@frac{#1}{#2}%
    \else
      \mbox{#1/#2}%
    \fi}
  \makeatother
\fi

\begin{document}
1/2$\frac{1}{2}\frac{12}{11}$
\end{document}
```

Here I assume that a vulgar fraction width is different than the width of the slashed form, which seems rather likely to happen.

However I would advise *not* to use vulgar fractions in a mathematical context.

Comment: Perhaps, it is better to introduce new command rather than touch `\frac` or modify `\tfrac` from `amsmath`.

Comment: @Igor That's what you asked! Of course it's better not to abuse the existing command.

Comment: There is another solution: $\mbox{1/2}$. If `amsmath` is loaded than $\text{1/2}$ is better. By the way, if Fractions is on, how one can break ligatures and obtain ordinary 1/2? I tried 1/{}2, 1{/}2 etc but did not succeed. The only way i found is $1/2$.

Comment: @Igor This is not a solution, as it will render with the slash if the fraction is not among the available characters. To disable the ligature in text mode, use `1/\/2` :)

Comment: `1\/\2` prints both 1 and 2 in position of superscrips though 2 should be in position of subscript. Secondly, I did not manage to find a fraction which would activate first brach (`\@@@frac{#1}{#2}`) of your code. Even `\frac{1}{Q}` takes second branch (`\mbox{#1/#2}`) but outputs Q in larger size than 1. It seems that comparing dimentions (`\ifdim\wd0=\wd2`) on my computer (MiKTeX 64bit) always evaluates to false. And `\ifdim\wd0<\wd2` is always evaluated to true.

Answer (score 35):

This answers your question title, but not your explanation (which seems to imply that you cannot use vulgar fractions with pdfLaTeX).  The `textcomp` package makes available `\textonehalf`, `\textonequarter`, and `\textthreequarters`. If your font and chosen encoding supports these, then they can be used directly.  (If your font does not support these, however, you will get an error message like `"\textonequarter" unavailable in encoding OT1"` or a strange symbol.)  This works with `pdfLaTeX`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{mathpazo}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{nicefrac} % For comparison
\usepackage{xfrac}    % Works better with other fonts
\begin{document}
\noindent Here are some vulgar fractions: \textonehalf, \textonequarter,
\textthreequarters.

\noindent Here are some \texttt{nicefrac} fractions:  \nicefrac{1}{2},
\nicefrac{1}{4}, \nicefrac{3}{4}, \nicefrac{11}{7}.

\noindent Here are some \texttt{xfrac} fractions:  \sfrac{1}{2},
\sfrac{1}{4}, \sfrac{3}{4}, \sfrac{11}{7}.
\end{document}
```

[image: Example of vulgar fractions with Palatino.]

Notice that, although the `xfrac` fractions look good, they do not have the same weight as the vulgar fractions designed with the font.  Unfortunately, `textcomp` only seems to provide access to these three fractions.  If you use LuaTeX or XeTeX, then you may be able to access additional glyphs provided in your font as [described by doncherry](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83052/6903).

Comment: Note that this isn't available in math-mode.

Comment: '\textonehalf' seems to remove all subsequent spaces, what am I doing wrong? *edit*: writing 'spin-{\textonehalf}' fixed it

Comment: @gen Many LaTeX commands will [eat subsequent spaces](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands) as they look for arguments.  See [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/31094/6903) for solutions. In short `\textonehalf{}`, or as you did, or wrap the command with the `xspace` package.

Comment: @mforbes Is there a list available of which fractions `textcomp` manages?

Comment: @LarsAbrahamsson Looking at [the source](https://github.com/latex3/latex2e/blob/master/base/ltoutenc.dtx), I believe that ½, ¼, and ¾ are the only ones supported.

Comment: @LarsAbrahamsson I have updated my answer: see the link to [doncherry's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/83052/6903) if you can use XeLaTeX or LuaTeX.

Comment: @mforbes I believe all LaTeX commands will eat subsequent spaces except for those commands like `\-` and `\%` which are named with a single symbol, because there would otherwise be no way to write something to output "_a" because `\textunderscorea` is taken to refer to a command called "textunderscorea," instead of the command "textunderscore" followed by the letter "a."

Comment: @AR-solidarityforModstrike Well... if you wrap the command using `xspace`, then it won't eat subsequent spaces, so it depends what you meant by "LaTeX commands".  (Or, if you like, it will eat the subsequent space then regurgitate it:-)

Answer (score 7):

The answer of @mforbes is correct, however, it can be simplified:

- The mathpazo package is not required.
- For XeLaTeX, the fontspec package is enough and textcomp package is not required.

Based on these, the minimal examples are the following:

For pdfLaTeX:

```
% !TeX program = pdflatex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{lmodern}

\begin{document}
    \textonehalf \textonequarter \textthreequarters
\end{document}
```

For XeLaTeX:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
    \textonehalf \textonequarter \textthreequarters
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: It there a list of available fractions available somewhere

Answer (score 6):

Do you mean something like the following?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\usepackage{iftex}
\newif\ifmodern\modernfalse
\ifXeTeX\moderntrue\fi
\ifLuaTeX\moderntrue\fi

\ifmodern
    \usepackage{unicode-math}
    \setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX,
        Extension=.otf,
        UprightFont= *-regular,
        BoldFont=*-bold,
        ItalicFont=*-italic,
        BoldItalicFont=*-bolditalic]{xits}
    \setmathfont{xits-math.otf}
\else
    \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\fi


\ifmodern
    \newcommand\half{\text{\char"00BD}}
\else
    \newcommand\half{\ensuremath{\frac12}}
\fi

\begin{document}
$a\half b$\half
\end{document}
```

Or do you want to redefine `\frac` itself?

Comment: Haha, `\ifmodern` ;-)

Comment: This is almost what I'd like to have. But final goal is a command like `\xfrac{nominator}{demumerator}` which would analise its arguments and outputs corresponding `\char`'s or ordinary `\frac` depending on availability of required glyphs.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure if this is what you want but an approach such as

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{ucs}
\usepackage[utf8x]{inputenc}

\begin{document}
\unichar{"00BD}

\end{document}
```

compiles with both `pdftex` and `xelatex`.

Comment: What id I don't want to load `usc` and `inputenc`? Where is `\unichar` defined? And how it differs from `\char`?

Comment: If you don't want to use `usc` and `inputenc` with `utf8x` (or at  least `utf8`) then this approach is not for you. To quote from [the unicode package documentation](http://ctan.org/pkg/unicode): "The `utf8x.def` definition file for use with `inputenc` covers a wider range of Unicode characters than does `utf8.def` in the LaTeX distribution. The `ucs` package provides facilities for efficient use of large sets of Unicode characters." In the example given `\unichar` is defined in [`ucs.sty`](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/unicode/ucs.sty) (see the definition of `uni@char`).