# Error in spacing when using custom command

Tags: spacing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands)

I`ve made a few very short commands, and they work, alas the spacing after them is wrong.

```
\newcommand{\yaksen}{$y$-aksen}
\newcommand{\xaksen}{$x$-aksen}
\newcommand{\zaksen}{$z$-aksen}
```

This produces no space after the commands, so if i type

```
this is an example \yaksen, is the norwegian term for the y-axis.
and the \zaksen is perpendicular to both the \xaksen and the \yaksen.
```

The output is

```
this is an example y-aksen, is the norwegian term for the y-axis.
and the z-aksenis perpendicular to both the x-aksenand the y-aksen.
```

However, putting blank spaces after the commands. Like this

```
\newcommand{\yaksen}{$y$-aksen }
\newcommand{\xaksen}{$x$-aksen }
\newcommand{\zaksen}{$z$-aksen }
```

Produces this

```
this is an example y-aksen , is the norwegian term for the y-axis.
and the z-aksen is perpendicular to both the x-aksen and the y-aksen .
```

Is there any easy way to obtain correct spacing? I think I`ve read something about it, but my searches ended in vain.

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands. If this answers your question, please leave a comment so that we can close this question and link it to the previous one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `\xspace` provided by the [`xspace` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace). It checks to see whether the character following a command sequence is a space or not, and inserts a space accordingly:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xspace}% http://ctan.org/pkg/xspace
\newcommand{\yaksen}{$y$-aksen\xspace}
\newcommand{\xaksen}{$x$-aksen\xspace}
\newcommand{\zaksen}{$z$-aksen\xspace}
\begin{document}
this is an example \yaksen, is the norwegian term for the y-axis.
and the \zaksen is perpendicular to both the \xaksen and the \yaksen.
\end{document}
```