# xmark that complements the ams checkmark

Tags: symbols

I am looking to have a xmark that complements the `\checkmark` symbol in the `amsmath` package. I've had a look at some in `symbols-a4.pdf` but can't seem to find the matching one! What symbol works well?

Comment: I normally use  `\text{\sffamily X}`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! That looks fine. It isn't quite as curly as the checkmark though.

Comment: If you remove the `\sffamily` it will print in serif font and it will be more curly!

Comment: It is best if you use the answer below. Learn to use packages, it is quite easy and it will be useful in your LaTex career.

Answer (score 356, accepted):

I would think your best bet might come from [`pifont`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont)'s dingbats:

[image: \checkmark and (\cmark + \xmark)]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}% http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb
\usepackage{pifont}% http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont
\newcommand{\cmark}{\ding{51}}%
\newcommand{\xmark}{\ding{55}}%
\begin{document}
\verb|\checkmark|: \checkmark \par
\verb|\cmark|: \cmark \par
\verb|\xmark|: \xmark
\end{document}
```

`\cmark` is defined as `\ding{51}`, while `\xmark` is defined as `\ding{55}`. Here is a list of the dingbat symbols, taken from the [`pifont` quick reference guide](http://willbenton.com/wb-images/pifont.pdf):

[image: pifont quick reference guide]

Comment: Great, thanks.The `\ding{55}` looks good. Making the `\xmark` command is useful too!

Comment: +1 but for those of you (just) looking to use `\checkmark`, i'd suggest using the `amsfonts` package instead of the `amssymb` package.  the `amssymb` package expands upon the more commonly used symbols defined in `amsfonts`, and includes some rare ones.  you might experience a noticeable increase in compile time if you use `amssymb` and don't need it.

Comment: Just tried this and `\ding{51}` and `\ding{55}` get evaluated to the numbers 3 and 7, respectively... anyone else have this issue?

Comment: Answer to A. Wan's question: you need to escape math mode for these characters to show correctly

Comment: A way to use it in math mode (or textmode) would be `\newcommand{\xmark}{\text{\ding{55}}}` for example.

Comment: @A.Wan I had the same problem as you, because I was using then inside dollar signs. I removed the signs and now it's good, maybe yours would be fine this way, too.

Comment: Using `\cmark`after setting it with the `\newcommand` doesn't add a space after in between text. My solution was to add `\ding{51}` directly.

Comment: @NunoLopes: See [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/5764)

Answer (score 16):

I thought drawing an xmark in tikz might be an elegant option. Here is my best attempt, together with a drawing of a checkmark.

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand{\tikzxmark}{%
\tikz[scale=0.23] {
    \draw[line width=0.7,line cap=round] (0,0) to [bend left=6] (1,1);
    \draw[line width=0.7,line cap=round] (0.2,0.95) to [bend right=3] (0.8,0.05);
}}
\newcommand{\tikzcmark}{%
\tikz[scale=0.23] {
    \draw[line width=0.7,line cap=round] (0.25,0) to [bend left=10] (1,1);
    \draw[line width=0.8,line cap=round] (0,0.35) to [bend right=1] (0.23,0);
}}

\begin{document}
\[
    \checkmark
    \tikzxmark
    \tikzcmark
\]
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is indeed elegant!

Answer (score 10):

If using XeLaTex is an option, then you could use one of Unicode's X mark (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_mark for a complete list).
All characters may not be available in your favorite font, but, [as noted in this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291955/34551), `DejaVu Sans` has a pretty good support.

On my installation, when I compile the following with XeLaTeX,

```
% !TeX TXS-program:compile = txs:///xelatex/
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xltxtra,xunicode}
\setmainfont{DejaVu Sans}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tabular}{c c c}
        Symbol & Unicode Codepoint (Hex) & Name\\
        ☐ & U+2610 & BALLOT BOX (checkbox)\\
        ☒ & U+2612 & BALLOT BOX WITH X (square with cross)\\
        ✗ & U+2717 & BALLOT X (cross)\\
        ✘ & U+2718 & HEAVY BALLOT X (bold cross)\\
        × & U+00D7 & MULTIPLICATION SIGN (z notation Cartesian product)\\
        ╳ & U+2573 & BOX DRAWINGS LIGHT DIAGONAL CROSS\\
        ☓ & U+2613 & SALTIRE (St Andrew's Cross)\\
        ✕ & U+2715 & MULTIPLICATION X\\
        ✖ & U+2716 & HEAVY MULTIPLICATION X\\
        ❌ & U+274C & CROSS MARK\\
        ❎ & U+274E & NEGATIVE SQUARED CROSS MARK\\
        ⨉ & U+2A09 & N-ARY TIMES OPERATOR\\
        ⨯ & U+2A2F & VECTOR OR CROSS PRODUCT\\
         & U+1F5D9 & CANCELLATION X\\
         & U+1F5F4 & BALLOT SCRIPT X\\
         & U+1F7A9 & LIGHT SALTIRE
    \end{tabular}
\end{document}
```

I obtain:

[image]

Note that it is possible to set the font to `DejaVu Sans` only for those symbols: again, follow the explanations at https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/291955/34551.

Answer (score 0):

Following @Werner's answer, try

```
\usepackage{pifont}
\newcommand{\cxmark}{\ding{51}\hspace{-1.75mm}\ding{55}}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! It will look strange if the two symbols overlap.

Comment: Thank you, @Jasper. 

I'm using it in a paper I write, and it looks good to me (check the one on the bottom): ![Checkmarks](https://imgur.com/a/nwsITVd)