# How to write checkmark in latex

Tags: symbols

I want to put some checkmarks inside table cells.

I have put a cross sign using `$\times$` but I really don't know how to write a checkmark in latex.

I used `\usepackage{bbding}` package and `\checkmark` but it doesnt work,

if it is \checkmark,  it shows nothing

if it is \Checkmark, it shows a `!`

an example source code:
(there is an additional cls file IEEEtran.cls : mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/IEEEtran/IEEEtran.cls)

```
    \documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}

    \ifCLASSINFOpdf
       \usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
       \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.pdf,.jpeg,.png,.eps}
    \else
       \usepackage[dvips]{graphicx}
       \DeclareGraphicsExtensions{.eps}
    \fi



    \usepackage{lscape}
    \usepackage{subfigure}
    \usepackage{dingbat}

    \begin{document}

    \title{0000}

    \author{\IEEEauthorblockN{00000}}


    \maketitle


    \begin{abstract}
    \end{abstract}

    \IEEEpeerreviewmaketitle

    \section{0000}
    ffffffffffff \Checkmark


    \begin{thebibliography}{1}

    \end{thebibliography}

    \end{document}
```

Comment: It should be `\Checkmark` - i.e. first letter capitalised.  Do the other symbols listed in the bbding manual work?

Comment: I tried \Checkmark, it doesn't work, pls see my update.

Comment: Both {`dingbat` & `\checkmark`} and {`bbding` & `\Checkmark`} work when plugged into your MWE for me, so I'm thinking installation issues, or some subtlety of your system.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `\ding{51}` from [`pifont`](http://ctan.org/pkg/pifont). See [X mark to match checkmark](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42619/5764).

Answer (score 106, accepted):

Without PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 
\begin{document}
This is a \checkmark checkmark.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: wow, this is great, but the shape is a little bit unlike a tick. how to make the left end longer?

Comment: A little bit of an overkill for a simple checkmark, isn't it? ;-)

Comment: @GonzaloMedina, I'm sure you're right, but on the other hand this is a really nice simple example for tikz - a sort of "hello world".  It gets my vote for generality and inspiration to try stuff.

Comment: Besides being an overkill or not, which is subjective, your solution has a problem and it is that it won't scale. Try  `\Huge This is a \checkmark\ checkmark.`

Comment: @ChrisH sure, it's inspiring, but, as I just mentioned, has problems (it doesn't scale when using font size switches).

Comment: @GonzaloMedina good point.  Now I want to make it scalable!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina and done - I'll put it up as an answer so I can include an image, then my approach can be criticised!

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Not really a problem, just set `x = 1em, y=1em` (and remove the `scale` option entirely). I’d just define `\newcommand*{\checktikz}[1][]{\tikz[x=1em, y=1em]\fill[#1] (0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}` which also allows `\checktikz[blue]` or even `\checktikz[rounded corners=.5pt, draw=red, ultra thin]`.

Comment: This seems to be the only answer with a checkmark. :-)

Answer (score 267):

Several options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

% amssymb
\checkmark

% bbding
\Checkmark
\CheckmarkBold

% pifont
\ding{51}
\ding{52}

% wasysym
\CheckedBox

\end{document}
```

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{dingbat}

\begin{document}

\checkmark

\end{document}
```

[image]

The `MnSymbol` package also offers `\checkmark`, but this package changes other symbols.

After the edit to the question:

```
\documentclass[conference]{IEEEtran}
\usepackage{dingbat}

\begin{document}

\title{0000}
\author{\IEEEauthorblockN{00000}}
\maketitle

\checkmark

\end{document}
```

[image]

(with `dingbat` it is `\checkmark`, lower case "c").

Comment: what package should I use except bbding?

Comment: @user1944267 depends on the checkmark style you want; I'd suggest you `amssymb` and its `\checkmark`.

Comment: still doesn't work, see my update

Comment: @user1944267 if you load `dingbat`, it's \checkmark with a lower case "c"; see my updated answer.

Comment: What about uncheckbox?

Answer (score 24):

Since the check mark is a Unicode symbol (U+2714), you can also use XeLaTeX.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Linux Libertine O}
\begin{document}
✔
\end{document}
```

Comment: Don’t forget: ☑ (U+2611, ‘Ballot Box with Check’), ✅ (U+2705, ‘White Heavy Check Mark’) and ✓ (U+2713, ‘Check Mark’). Yours is called ‘Heavy Check Mark’.

Comment: @canaaerus Very good, I wasn't aware (U+2714 is the only check mark in the Linux Libertine font).

Comment: (I happen not to have the ✔ character on Mac OS X when using Linux Libertine O.)

Answer (score 11):

This is a scaleable version of the checkmark in the answer by PGFTricks above.  I'm sure there's a better way though.

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{calc}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 
\def\scalecheck{\resizebox{\widthof{\checkmark}*\ratio{\widthof{x}}{\widthof{\normalsize x}}}{!}{\checkmark}}
%that's defined it - now for a test

\begin{document}

This is a \checkmark checkmark.

\huge 
This is a huge \scalecheck checkmark in huge text.

\footnotesize
This is a footnotesize \scalecheck checkmark in footnotesize text.
\end{document}
```

[image: Example]

Comment: `\fillscale=0.4` is probably only a type, right? Anyway, it would be better to just use font units directly: the most simple way would be to directly set `x` and `y`: `\tikz[x=1em, y=1em]` and remove the `scale` option entirely.

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel I've edited to escape the opening square bracket, now it looks OK - not sure why I need to do that on that line but not after `\documentclass`.  I've tested it with your change, and I prefer that way of doing it - but my code was based on the answer above.