# How to draw checkmark inside a colored circle in latex?

Tags: circles

Referring to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132783/how-to-write-checkmark-in-latex), how can I draw a checkmark inside a solid circle as shown as a picture?

Regards

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZefqB.png]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Without `tikz`

```
\documentclass{article}
%\usepackage{dingbat}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx,xcolor}

\newcommand\circledmark[1][red]{%
  \ooalign{%
    \hidewidth
    \kern0.65ex\raisebox{-0.9ex}{\scalebox{3}{\textcolor{#1}{\textbullet}}}
    \hidewidth\cr
    $\checkmark$\cr
  }%
}

\newcommand\circled[1][red]{%
    \raisebox{-0.9ex}{\scalebox{3}{\textcolor{#1}{\textbullet}}}
  }%

\begin{document}

This is circled \circledmark\quad\circledmark[cyan] and filled \circled[cyan]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 10):

One option:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\begin{document}

\textcircled{$\checkmark$}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, with color:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\newcommand\circledmark[1][red]{%
\textcolor{#1}{\textcircled{\normalcolor$\checkmark$}}%
}

\begin{document}

\circledmark\quad\circledmark[cyan]

\end{document}
```

[image]

suppress `\normalcolor` if the color is also for the checkmark.

Or, using TikZ and a filled circle, two options:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\circledmark[1][red!50]{%
  \tikz\node[circle,fill=#1,inner sep=0pt]{$\checkmark$};%
}

\newcommand\circledmarki[1][red!50]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(A.south)]{
    \node[circle,fill=#1,inner sep=0.75ex] (A) {};
    \node at (A) {$\checkmark$};
  }%  
}

\begin{document}

\circledmark\quad\circledmark[cyan!60]\quad\circledmarki\quad\circledmarki[cyan!60]

\end{document}
```

[image]

And, after a request in a comment:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand\circledmark[1][red!50]{%
  \tikz\node[circle,fill=#1,inner sep=0pt]{$\checkmark$};%
}

\newcommand\circledmarki[1][red!50]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(A.south)]{
    \node[circle,fill=#1,inner sep=0.75ex] (A) {};
    \node at (A) {$\checkmark$};
  }%  
}

\newcommand\mycircle[1][red!50]{%
  \tikz[baseline=(A.south)]{
    \node[circle,fill=#1,inner sep=0.75ex] {};
  }%  
}

\begin{document}

\circledmark\quad\circledmark[cyan!60]\quad
\circledmarki\mycircle\quad\circledmarki[cyan!60]\mycircle[cyan!60]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Great! but i need the same but filled circle and enclosing checkbox fully.

Comment: @manish please see my updated answer.

Comment: Nice! We should remember that we can use light colors: `cyan!40` for example.

Comment: @Sigur good suggestion. I'veincorporated it to my answer.

Comment: @GonzaloMedina Thanks for quick reply can i draw one circle with no tick mark inside. I mean 2 circles side by side one with tick mark and other without.

Comment: @manish Sure. Please see my updated answer; something like that?

Comment: @GonzaloMedina I need to draw independent solid circle without tick, i can put myself side by side.

Comment: @manish please see my updated answer.