# Checkmark with cross

Tags: symbols

Is there a symbol similar to following one that can be used to express satisfaction with minor disturbance?

[image]

Comment: Do you have any reference for this symbol? What does it stand for? Why not using a [cross](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_mark)? If you have some nice reference or a real use for that, it could get recommended to the unicode. Until now, I do not know it.

Comment: @LaRiFaRi, in fact I do not know any reference. If there is a symbol that means 'ok perfect, but there is a small defect', I appreciate your suggestions.

Comment: are you allowed to take colors?

Comment: There is a Unicode character called "Not Check Mark" that resembles your drawing: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/636101/how-to-input-not-check-mark-in-latex

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As this symbol does not exist in unicode, you will have to define your own symbol. For starting, you should choose a check-mark you like (from my MWE below). With this, you can overlay this checkmark with some small rule or scaled backslash or alike.

```
% arara: lualatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\newcommand{\test}[1]{\setmainfont{#1}
    \symbol{"2714}
    \symbol{"2718}
    \symbol{"2713}  
    \symbol{"2717}\par}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\def\faChecked{\FA\symbol{"F00C}}
\def\faCrossed{\FA\symbol{"F00D}}

\begin{document}
$\checkmark$\setmathfont{XITS Math}$\checkmark$\setmathfont{Asana Math}$\checkmark$\setmathfont{TeX Gyre Pagella Math}$\checkmark$

\test{dejavusans.ttf}
\test{Linux Libertine O}
\test{symbola.ttf}
\test{quivira.otf}

\faChecked\faCrossed
\end{document}
```

[image]

Most of these symbols are having a nice calligraphic line which I would prefer to retain. Therefore you could take one of the cross-signs and cut away its "slash"-bar getting a nice "back-slash"-bar (I would do this in an external program).

More easy would be, to choose a combination you like and to overlay these two. You might scale down the cross until it fits into the long arm of the check-mark, but I would recommend to use it as a superscript and to kern it a bit onto the left. Giving it a certain colour could make a clear and understandable symbol. What you think?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{fontspec}

\begin{document}
\setmainfont{quivira.otf}
\textcolor{green}{\symbol{"2713}}\textsuperscript{\textcolor{red}{\kern-0.55em\tiny\symbol{"2717}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

---

**Edit**: If you find symbols for PDFLaTeX, you can use them the very same way. I found the checkmarks from `bbding` (very rastered) and `pifont` which I present below:

```
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{pifont}

\begin{document}
    % bbding commands (too pixeled...)
    \Checkmark\CheckmarkBold\XSolidBrush
    % pifont commands
    \ding{51}\ding{52}\ding{55}\ding{56}    

\textcolor{green}{\ding{51}}\textsuperscript{\textcolor{red}{\kern-0.5em\tiny\ding{55}}}
\end{document}
```

Comment: this is a good solution. However, is it possible to use `pdflatex`?

Comment: @Kadir see my edit!

Comment: Thanks! I am using this: `\textcolor{black}{\ding{51}}{\small\textcolor{black}{\kern-0.7em\ding{55}}}`

Comment: @Kadir Glad you like it. You may leave the colours away. Black is the default.

Answer (score 5):

My final solution:

```
\checkmark\kern-1.1ex\raisebox{.7ex}{\rotatebox[origin=c]{125}{--}}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on [How to write checkmark in latex](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/132783/how-to-write-checkmark-in-latex)

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\def\halfcheckmark{\tikz\draw[scale=0.4,fill=black](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle (0.75,0.2) -- (0.77,0.2)  -- (0.6,0.7) -- cycle;}


\begin{document}
This a half check mark: \halfcheckmark
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Hey Fabio, it would improve your answer if you added a picture of the output that your code generates.