# How to input ⍻(not check mark) in latex?

Tags: symbols, unicode, unicode-math

I want to know how to input not check mark in LaTeX.
Information of this symbol: https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+237B

Comment: Are you using PDFLaTeX, XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hope it helps You (I'v tried)

[image]

```
\documentclass[tikz]{article}
\usepackage{ulem} 
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{cancel}

\def\halfcheckmark{\tikz\draw[scale=0.4,fill=black](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle (0.75,0.2) -- (0.77,0.2)  -- (0.6,0.7) -- cycle;}

\newcommand{\notcheckmark}{{$\surd$}\textsuperscript{\textcolor{black}{\kern-0.35em{\bf--}}}}


\begin{document}

0) \notcheckmark\\


1)% bbding
\bcancel{\Checkmark} or \bcancel{\CheckmarkBold}\\


2) \halfcheckmark\\

% cancel
3) \( \bcancel{\surd} \)\\

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6):

If you're using legacy fonts on pdflatex, you can use the bar text accent in a similar way as `\hbar` is built.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\newcommand{\notcheckmark}{\checkmark\makebox[0pt][r]{\normalfont\symbol{'26}}}

\begin{document}

\checkmark \notcheckmark \checkmark

\notcheckmark \checkmark \notcheckmark

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

The following code works with both XeLaTeX and LuaLaTeX and a suitably chosen Oentype math font. (For XeLaTeX, you may need to adjust the `Path` option suitably to match the features of your TeX distribution.)

The key is to choose a math font that actually features a glyph for unicode code 237B (hex). As the following example shows, the font `Stix Two Math` features this glyph, whereas `Stix Two Text` does not. (The `=` symbols are there just to provide an impression of the size of the glyph.) Incidentally, the Opentupe math font `Cambria Math` also features a glyph for slot 237B (hex).

[image]

```
%% This program needs to be compiled with XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\usepackage{iftex}
\ifxetex
  \defaultfontfeatures{Path=/usr/local/texlive/2021/texmf-dist/fonts/opentype/public/stix2-otf/}
  \setmainfont{STIXTwoText-Regular}
  \setmathfont{STIXTwoMath-Regular}
\else\ifluatex
  \setmainfont{Stix Two Text}
  \setmathfont{Stix Two Math}
\fi\fi

\begin{document}
=\char"237B=

=$\char"237B$=
\end{document}
```