# Double checkmark symbol

Tags: stacking-symbols

How do I produce double checkmarks? Similar to this:

[image]

```
\rlap{\checkmark}\checkmark
```

overlaps one on the other

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Rather than `\checkmark` from the [amssymb](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/amssymb) package this symbols looks closure to `\checked` from [wasysym](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/wasysym). You can use:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\newcommand\doublecheck{\textcolor{blue}{\checked\kern-0.6em\checked}}

\begin{document}

    \doublecheck

\end{document}
```

to produce:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer, I've marked this as solved.

Answer (score 10):

Just for fun (meaning that @Andrew's answer is the one that should be accepted): a Ti*k*Zy proposal.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pics/.cd, 
checkmark/.style={code={% starting point : https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/132790/121799
\pgfgettransformentries{\tmpxx}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}{\tmp}
\draw[line width=\tmpxx*1pt,blue!80,fill=blue!60,line join=bevel] (0,.35) -- (.25,0) to[bend left=5] (0.8,.6) to[bend
right=5] (.25,.18) -- cycle;}}}
\newcommand{\doubleckmark}{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(0,0)}]
\path (0,0) pic[scale=0.4]{checkmark} (0.12,0) pic[scale=0.4]{checkmark};
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\pic{checkmark};
\end{tikzpicture}

abc \doubleckmark\ xyz  

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 I vote for marmot's answer as it fulfills the two colour requirement

Comment: Nice, but the slope is not steep enough and the colours are not the same.

Comment: @AndréC Thanks! Yes, I know that this is not an exact match, but the OP says "similar to". Of course, if the OP gives me more feedback, I'll be happy to adjust the graphics.

Comment: Thank you very much @marmot you gave me exactly what I needed. The slope and colors are minor details irrelevant to my needs.

Comment: @Andrew I agree too and I vote positively.