# How to add utf-8 symbols correctly?

Tags: unicode, text

I want to add these two utf-8 symbols ☐ , ⌧  in my latex document, I also added `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`. How can I do that?

My input should look like this: 
[image]

Comment: Well: is your file utf8? Are you using pdflatex or xelatex? Also what do you need the symbols for? The usage might change how you can insert them.

Comment: @Alenanno just have editted my question.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you use a Unicode engine (`xetex` or `luatex`) it is just a matter of finding a font, which offers these symbols.  I have expereinced the DejaVu Sans font to be pretty complete in that regard.  You might not want to change the font of the whole document just for these symbols, so it becomes necessary to allocate a `\newfontfamily` which I named `\boxedsymbols`.  Then you can locally switch fonts to print the exotic symbols.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\boxedsymbols{DejaVu Sans}
\begin{document}
Here we go: {\boxedsymbols ☐ ⌧}
\end{document}
```

> [image]

For `pdflatex`, there is the possibility to make the Unicode characters active and define them to print a symbol, that is available in the font, which looks similar.  Here I use the math symbols `\square` and `\boxtimes` (from `amssymb`).  Note, that these are *not* the actual Unicode symbols which you enter in your document, but rather visual equivalents.

If you want to use them in math-mode as well, replace `$<symbol>$` by `\ensuremath{<symbol>}`.  (This is one of the rare cases, where `\ensuremath` is appropriate.)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amssymb}% for \boxtimes
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{☐}{$\square$}
\newunicodechar{⌧}{$\boxtimes$}
\begin{document}
Here we go: ☐ ⌧
\end{document}
```

> [image]

The functionality obtained with the `pdflatex` solution, namely typing the symbols directly without having to switch fonts, seems appealing and can also be achieved with the `xetex`/`luatex` variant.  Bear in mind, that this is not really a good practice, as now the characters `☐`, `⌧` are active and code is executed each time they are encountered in the text.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newfontfamily\boxedsymbols{DejaVu Sans}
\newunicodechar{☐}{{\boxedsymbols\char`☐}}
\newunicodechar{⌧}{{\boxedsymbols\char`⌧}}
\begin{document}
Here we go: ☐ ⌧
\end{document}
```

The output is the same as for the first variant.

Answer (score 11):

You can load the `wasysym` package and use these commands. Note the `\` being used to preserve the space after a macro.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{wasysym}

\begin{document}

Do you like \LaTeX? \Square\ Yes – \Square\ No

You can answer using \CheckedBox\ or \XBox, but don't leave it empty!

\end{document}
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks! That's exactly what I need!

Comment: Is it just me, or does the `\CheckedBox` symbol look a bit off with respect to the placement of the check mark inside the box?

Comment: @Sverre I think it's the screenshot.

Comment: I think `\CheckedBox` is the only admissible answer to the question in your example!

Comment: @HenriMenke Why? :P