# Is there a LaTeX version of the left-handed tick mark?

Tags: symbols

I am looking for a way to encode this symbol:[image]

This is the natural check mark for a left-handed person, as this is what happens when we apply an outward flick of the wrist to a pen.  However, all the checkmarks I have found for LaTeX are right-handed.

Answer (score 15):

Sure thing! Reflect the regular `\checkmark` (from [`amssymb`](http://ctan.org/pkg/amssymb)) using [`graphicx`](http://ctan.org/pkg/graphicx)'s `\reflectbox`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amssymb,graphicx}

\newcommand{\lcheckmark}{\reflectbox{\checkmark}}

\begin{document}

\verb| \checkmark|: \checkmark \par
\verb|\lcheckmark|: \lcheckmark

\end{document}
```

Comment: Also see [X mark to match checkmark](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/42619/5764)

Answer (score 4):

For the sake of completeness, there also some others (right-handed) related symbols:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{bbding}
\usepackage{fontawesome}
\let\Cross\undefined % oooppsss...
\usepackage{marvosym}
\usepackage{wasysym}
\begin{document}\huge
\faCheck{ } 
\faCheckCircle{ }
\faCheckCircleO{ }
\faCheckSquare{ }
\CheckmarkBold{ } 
\Checkmark{ }
$\checked$
\CheckedBox{ } 
\end{document}
```

But if you are tired of packages of symbols:

[image: mwe]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}\huge
\rotatebox[origin=c]{-120}{\sffamily 7} checked
\end{document}
```