# Checkmark in XeLatex

Tags: xetex

I am working with Tex Studio and using XeLatex compiler. When using \checkmark in the table shows a hollow box instead of symbol. Based on the internet search, I have used packages such as \pifont and \amssymb but no success. 
If I change the compiler to pdfLatex, the checkmarks are visible.

Thank you for help in advance.

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
$\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{4cm} p{1cm} p{1cm} p{1cm} p{1cm} p{1cm} p{1cm}|}  \hline 
        Location    & $u_x$     & $u_y$     & $u_z$ & $\phi_x$ & $\phi_y$ & $\phi_z$ \\ \hline\hline
        Main Wall Bottom    &   \checkmark  & \checkmark    & \checkmark    & \checkmark & NDoF & \checkmark\\ \hline
        Pier Bottom     &   \checkmark  & \checkmark    & \checkmark    & NDoF &\checkmark  & \checkmark\\ \hline
        Main Wall Top   &   \checkmark  & \checkmark    & - & \checkmark & NDoF & \checkmark\\ \hline
        Pier Top    &   \checkmark  & \checkmark    & - & NDoF &\checkmark &  \checkmark\\ \hline
        Pier Vertical   &   \checkmark  & \checkmark    & - &  NDoF & \checkmark &\checkmark\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Boundary conditions "-"= Not restricted; "NDof"= Element do not have respective degree of freedom } 
    \label{tab:element-bc}
\end{center}
\end{table}$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Show a complete example that can be used for tests.

Comment: Maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/415344/34551 could be a beginning? Could you try to just type one of the unicode sign, e.g. ☑ , ✅ ,  ✓ ,  ✔ ,   or   (cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Check_mark#Unicode), compile it with XeLaTex, and see how it goes? (And, @UlrikeFischer is referring to this: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/34551).

Answer (score 1):

If I remove the faulty and add \usepackage{amssymb} the checkmarks are there.
Compiled with

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (TeX Live `2019/W32TeX)
```

Corrected code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amssymb}%
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\begin{center}
    \begin{tabular}{|p{4cm} p{1cm} p{1cm} p{1cm} p{1cm} p{1cm} p{1cm}|}  \hline
        Location    & $u_x$     & $u_y$     & $u_z$ & $\phi_x$ & $\phi_y$ & $\phi_z$ \\ \hline\hline
        Main Wall Bottom    &   \checkmark  & \checkmark    & \checkmark    & \checkmark & NDoF & \checkmark\\ \hline
        Pier Bottom     &   \checkmark  & \checkmark    & \checkmark    & NDoF &\checkmark  & \checkmark\\ \hline
        Main Wall Top   &   \checkmark  & \checkmark    & - & \checkmark & NDoF & \checkmark\\ \hline
        Pier Top    &   \checkmark  & \checkmark    & - & NDoF &\checkmark &  \checkmark\\ \hline
        Pier Vertical   &   \checkmark  & \checkmark    & - &  NDoF & \checkmark &\checkmark\\ \hline
    \end{tabular}
    \caption{Boundary conditions "-"= Not restricted; "NDof"= Element do not have respective degree of freedom }
    \label{tab:element-bc}
\end{center}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for a prompt reply, I am using amssymbol too but no luck.

Comment: Then show your log file of my example

Comment: This is XeTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-0.999991 (MiKTeX 2.9.7140 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2019.8.21)  23 AUG 2019 12:29
entering extended mode
**./report.tex
(report.tex
LaTeX2e <2018-12-01>
(tudelft-report.cls
Document Class: tudelft-report 2013/06/22 v1.0 TU Delft thesis class

Comment: My example and your code don't use tudelft-report.cls. If you want a sensible answer you shouldn't invent some code but show a real example.