# Incorrect mark with TIKZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, mark

Any idea on how to design a nice incorrect mark using TIKZ, which is the opposite of the mark below:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\checkmark{\tikz\fill[scale=0.4](0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;} 
\begin{document}
This is a \checkmark checkmark.
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: perhaps an answer is here : https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/42619/x-mark-to-match-checkmark/42620

Comment: I always use `\CheckmarkBold` and `\XSolidBrush` from the  [bbding](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/bbding) package.

Comment: @AlainMatthes using TIKZ

Comment: strange idea but you have have an example. You need only to get the coordinates. A good way it's to place the symbol (from a font)  on a grid

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you *really* want to do this using [tikz](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/tikz) then how does this look:

[image]

Here is the code:

```
\documentclass[preview,border=12pt,varwidth]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\newcommand\checkmark[1][]{%
  \tikz[scale=0.4,#1]{\fill(0,.35) -- (.25,0) -- (1,.7) -- (.25,.15) -- cycle;}%
}
\newcommand\crossmark[1][]{%
  \tikz[scale=0.4,#1]{
    \fill(0,0)--(0.1,0) .. controls (0.5,0.4) .. (1,0.7)--(0.9,0.7) ..  controls (0.5,0.5) ..(0,0.1) --cycle;
    \fill(1,0.1)--(0.9,0.1) .. controls (0.5,0.3) .. (0,0.7)--(0.1,0.7) .. controls (0.5,0.4) ..(1,0.2) --cycle;
  }%
}
\begin{document}
This is a \checkmark~checkmark.

This is a \crossmark~crossmark.

Here are coloured versions \checkmark[green]~and \crossmark[red, scale=1].
\end{document}
```

As the last examples show, I have given both macros an optional argument so that you can add extra style.