# Counting the total number of theorems

Tags: theorems, counters, amsthm

I have:

```
\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
....
\begin{problem}...\end{problem}...
...
\begin{problem}...\end{problem}...
```

In the first page of the document, how can I know the number of the problem environments used in the document? That is, I want to know the value of the last `problem` counter.

Comment: You are looking for `\value{problem}` or maybe `\the\value{problem}` depending on where you want to use it.

Comment: @Seamus I don't want to sound harsh, but wouldn't `\the\value{problem}` return `0` at the beginning of the document no matter the number of `problem`s?

Comment: @tohecz Perhaps I misunderstood the question, but I took it to be about accessing the number of problems so far, at a point in the document. If you want to know the value of the problem counter at the _end_ of the document, then my suggestion will work.

Comment: @Seamus Chang says "In the first page of the document, ..."

Comment: @tohecz Seamus says "Perhaps I misunderstood the question …"

Comment: @Seamus and tohecz: Chang says "Thank you for your answers."

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The following code uses the `.aux` file for that. It provides a macro `\total@problems` that sets `\totalproblems` to its parameter. And calls this macro at the end of document to store the value of counter `problem`. You need to run twice, and there is `0` stored at the first run.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}

% STARTS HERE
\makeatletter
\AtEndDocument{\write\@auxout{\protect\total@problems{\arabic{problem}}}}
\def\total@problems#1{\global\def\totalproblems{#1}}
\total@problems{0}
\makeatother
% ENDS HERE

\begin{document}

Number of problems: \totalproblems

....
\begin{problem}...\end{problem}...
...
\begin{problem}...\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks. It works good. I wrote `There are \totalproblems problems.`, and it returns `There are 5problems.` What is a good workaround for the spacing without manually adding a space?

Comment: @Chang the manual space is simply a matter of writing `\ ` (that is, backslash, space) `There are \totalproblems\ problems.` Or look at the `xspace` package.

Comment: @Seamus Yes, I know `\ `. But why should `\totalproblems problems` not be `5 problems`?

Comment: The package `totcount` does something similar.

Comment: @Chang [because the space after a macro is ignored.](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/215)

Comment: @Chang An alternative to Seamus's solution is `\totalproblems{} problems`

Comment: @egreg How can the `totcount` package be used to solve this problem?

Comment: @user4514 I've added an answer

Comment: @egreg Perfect!

Answer (score 11):

The package `totcount` provides a very efficient solution. It's sufficient to register the counter to the list of "total counters".

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{totcount}

\newtheorem{problem}{Problem}
\regtotcounter{problem} % register the counter for getting the total

\begin{document}

Number of problems: \total{problem}

\begin{problem}
A
\end{problem}

\begin{problem}
B
\end{problem}

\end{document}
```

Using `\total{problem}` will print the required number; LaTeX will warn if another run is needed because of changes in the total.

Comment: the first time I compile it gives me ?? and the second time it shows 0. Why? I have written more than 100 problems.

Comment: @yngabl I'm sorry, but I get 2 with the example code. Maybe you have some different setting.