# How to customize the exercise package?

Tags: exercises

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed,exercisedelayed]{exercise}
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{Exercise}


\begin{document}
{


\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{Classical physics}
\section*{The good old days}
For every $\epsilon>0$
\begin{Exercise}[label={afaff}, name={Exercice}, difficulty={1}]
sfsf
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
aggsg f
\end{Answer}


\chapter{Modern physics}
\section*{Departure from classical physics}
There exists a $\delta>0$
\begin{Exercise}[label={dghd}, name={Exercice}, difficulty={2}]
b7dyfas789
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
hjsdgfkihsk 
\end{Answer}


\chapter{Neoclassical physics}
\section{Guess who's back}
\begin{Exercise}[label={NQCD}, name={Exercice}, difficulty={3}]
skjhfkshf
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
b78asghfkighkia
\end{Answer}


\part{Exercises}
\shipoutExercise

\part{Solutions}
\shipoutAnswer


\end{document}
```

In the last two parts, the exercises are shown without any reference to the chapters. How can I make them like this:

> Chaptername
>
> its exercises
>
> chaptername
>
> its exercises
>
> etc

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. Another package you could try out is `xsim`.

Comment: @Johannes_B It seems good I never used it but I already wrote hundreds of exercises using the exercise package.

Comment: Do you mean "customize"? I hope you mean "costumize".

Comment: You can use [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/47895/32995) to get the number of exercises.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you would like to number to exercises within chapters.

I've used [xassoccnt](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/xassoccnt) to print the total number of exercises.

I've modified `\ExerciseHeader` and `\AnswerHeader` to print the Chapter number and name before its exercises when you ship out them.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{book}
\usepackage[lastexercise,answerdelayed,exercisedelayed]{exercise}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseName}{Exercice}
\renewcommand{\AnswerName}{Exercice}
\usepackage{totcount}
\regtotcounter{Exercise} % register the counter for getting the total
\usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{Exercise}{chapter}
\counterwithin{Answer}{chapter}
\usepackage{xassoccnt}
\NewTotalDocumentCounter{totalex}
\usepackage{titleref}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{ \stepcounter{totalex}\ifnumcomp{\value{Exercise}}{=}{1}{\ifnumcomp{\thechapter}{=}{1}{}{\vspace{10pt}}\noindent\Large\textbf{Chapter\ \thechapter\ \currenttitle}\par\vspace{10pt}}{}\noindent\normalsize\bfseries\ExerciseName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB\ \ExerciseHeaderDifficulty\par\medskip}
\renewcommand{\AnswerHeader}{\ifnumcomp{\value{Exercise}}{=}{1}{\ifnumcomp{\thechapter}{=}{1}{}{\vspace{10pt}}\noindent\Large\textbf{Chapter\ \thechapter\ \currenttitle}\par\vspace{10pt}}{}\noindent\normalsize\bfseries\AnswerName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB\ \ExerciseHeaderDifficulty\par\medskip}

\usepackage{hyperref}

\begin{document}
This document contains \TotalValue{totalex} solved exercises.

\tableofcontents
\mainmatter

\chapter{Classical physics}
\makeatletter

\makeatother
\section*{The good old days}
For every $\epsilon>0$
\begin{Exercise}[label={afaff}, difficulty={1}]
sfsf
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
aggsg f
\end{Answer}
\begin{Exercise}[difficulty={2}]
another exercise
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
another answer
\end{Answer}
\begin{Exercise}[difficulty={1}]
one more exercise
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
one more answer
\end{Answer}
\chapter{Modern physics}
\section*{Departure from classical physics}
There exists a $\delta>0$
\begin{Exercise}[label={dghd}, difficulty={2}]
b7dyfas789
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
hjsdgfkihsk 
\end{Answer}

\chapter{Neoclassical physics}
\section{Guess who's back}
\begin{Exercise}[label={NQCD}, difficulty={3}]
skjhfkshf
\end{Exercise}
\begin{Answer}
b78asghfkighkia
\end{Answer}

\part{Exercises}
\shipoutExercise

\part{Solutions}
\shipoutAnswer

\end{document}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you. Just one more thing. The exercises are numbered continuously without the chap number. So in this example chap 3 begins with exercise 5.

Comment: @Trump Have you copied in your doc also these lines `usepackage{chngcntr}
\counterwithin{Exercise}{chapter}
\counterwithin{Answer}{chapter}`?

Comment: If I add them the exercises are numbered with chapter number. If I remove them the exercises are numbered continuously but only the name of the first chapter appears in the exercises part.

Comment: @Trump Have you got this line `\renewcommand{\ExerciseHeader}{ \stepcounter{totalex}\ifnumcomp{\value{Exercise}}{=}{1}{\ifnumcomp{\thechapter}{=}{1}{}{\vspace{10pt}}\noindent\Large\textbf{Chapter\ \thechapter\ \currenttitle}\par\vspace{10pt}}{}\noindent\normalsize\bfseries\ExerciseName\ \ExerciseHeaderNB\ \ExerciseHeaderDifficulty\par\medskip}
` in your actual document?

Comment: Yes I get [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JsNGo.png).

Comment: @Trump But what I see is the output without the numbering within the chapter, if you want a continuous numbering all along the document, my code has to be changed, I test the number 1 to understand if it is the first exercise of the chapter. If you want the continuos numering you have to use a boolean like `\newboolean{firstanswerofthechapter}  
` here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/371320/101651.