# How to total item counts in multiple enumerate environments, respecting \include

Tags: enumerate, counters, include, totcount, mdwtools

I'm writing a book in which each chapter ends with a list of numbered exercises.  I would like to persuade LaTeX to count the total number of exercises in the book, to be referred to with `\ref` or something like it (e.g., `\total` from `totcount`).  Each chapter is loaded separately using `\include`, and I want the counts to be correct even when using `\includeonly`.

It looks like [the `totcount` package](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/47892/counting-the-total-number-of-theorems) might help, provided I somehow jigger the exercise environments to step a suitable counter.  But I'm not quite clear on how I can do that in a way that is compatible with the `\suspend` and `\resume` commands from package `mdwlist`.

Any suggestions how I would define an `exercises` environment that would work with `totcount` and be compatible with `\suspend` and `\resume`?  Or suggest another approach entirely?

Here's an MWE in which each exercise is correctly numbered: exercises in chapter 1 are numbered 1 to 4, as are exercises in chapter 2.  The problem I'm trying to solve is to accumulate the correct total (8) in the preface.

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{totcount}
\usepackage{mdwlist}

\newtotcounter{exercises}
\newenvironment{exercises}
   {\enumerate}     % need something here to count each exercise
   {\endenumerate}



\begin{document}

\section*{Preface}

There are \total{exercises} exercises.  (Should be~8.)

% this chapter meant to be in a separate file loaded with \include
\chapter{Diet}

\section{Omnivorous}

\begin{exercises}
\item
Which do you prefer?
\begin{enumerate} 
\item
Fish
\item
Fowl
\end{enumerate}
\item
What won't you touch?
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Snakes
\item
Snails
\end{enumerate}
\suspend{exercises}

\section{Vegetarian}

\resume{exercises}
\item
Which do you prefer?
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Corn
\item
Squash
\end{enumerate}
\item
What won't you touch?
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Broccoli
\item
Cilantro
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercises}


% this chapter meant to be in a separate file loaded with \include
\chapter{Technology}

\section{Typesetting}

\begin{exercises}
\item
Which do you prefer?
\begin{enumerate} 
\item
Plain \TeX
\item
\LaTeX
\end{enumerate}
\item
What won't you touch?
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Word
\item
Scribe
\end{enumerate}
\suspend{exercises}

\section{Operating systems}

\resume{exercises}
\item
Which do you prefer?
\begin{enumerate}
\item
Debian
\item
Arch
\end{enumerate}
\item
What won't you touch?
\begin{enumerate}
\item
BeOS
\item
NeXT
\end{enumerate}
\end{exercises}

\end{document}
```

Comment: You can also modify/rename an environment to increment a new counter each time.  \refsteprcounter and \label to save the last value (plus one).

Comment: Can you please post a [minimal working example](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that shows what your exercises look like. Your document class, for example, might be relevant to the solution. It sounds like you are using the [enumitem](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/enumitem) package. Is this right?

Comment: @Andrew for MWE do you recommend separate file for each chapter?

Comment: I asked for a MWE as it is not clear to me what you are trying to do. A MWE should clarify this and show the packages that you need. Your example code is not so helpful as it's a snippet that is not well explained and does not compile. Can you clearly describe what want. In particular, how are the exercises numbered, how and where do you want to refer back to the number of exercises? Is it essential that you use `\suspend` and `\resume` or are these just commands that you think might help? Please add either a MWE or a mock-up of the output you want.

Comment: @Andrew ack!  Hadn't realized the problem was unclear.  Let's hope the MWE at least states precisely what problem I am trying to solve.

Comment: Avoid `mdwlist`: last version dated 1996.

Answer (score 0):

You can define your own environment and counters.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{expl3}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% define and initialize exercise counter
\int_new:N \g_exercise_count_int
\int_gset:Nn \g_exercise_count_int {0}

\NewDocumentEnvironment{exercise}{O{}}{
    % increment counter when environment starts
    \int_gincr:N \g_exercise_count_int
    % forward optional arguments
    \begin{enumerate}[#1]
}{
    \end{enumerate}
}

\newcommand{\exercisecount}{
    \int_use:N \g_exercise_count_int
}

\ExplSyntaxOff


\begin{exercise}[font=\bfseries]
\item Question 1
\item Question 2
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}[label=\Roman*.]
\item Question 1
\item Question 2
\end{exercise}

\begin{exercise}
\item Question 1
\item Question 2
\end{exercise}

Number of exercises: \exercisecount


\end{document}
```

Answer (score 0):

A minimal working example was requested, but I decided the time required to prepare one might be better spend on trying to solve the problem.  I defined an `exercises` environment intended to behave like `enumerate` and also to keep track of the total number of exercises in the book.  I also used package `totcounter`.
Here's what I learned:

- You can't just ask `\item` to increment a counter for you, because that would increment inside nested lists.
- It would work to ask to increment a counter at the end of an `exercises` environment, except the `\suspend` macro from package `mdwlist` ends an environment multiple times.  I tried a few tricks, like defining a hook for various suspended environments, but in the end a simple `\ifsuspended` was easier to get working.  This condition enables the `\end{exercises}` to tell the difference between truly ending and just being suspended.

Code below.

```
\newtotcounter{exercises}

\newif\ifexercising

\makeatletter



\newenvironment{exercises}
  {\ifexercising
      \@latexerr{Nested exercises}{Don't nest exercise environments}%
   \else
     \exercisingtrue
     \ifnum \@listdepth >1\relax
       \@latexerr{Nested exercises}{Don't put exercises inside another list}%
     \fi
   \fi
   \enumerate
  }
  {\ifsuspended\else\addtocounter{exercises}{\value{enumi}}\fi
   \endenumerate
  }

\def\@suspend@exercises{\addtocounter{exercises}{-\value{enumi}}}

\newif\ifsuspended
\suspendedfalse

\def\suspend@i[#1]#2{%
  \edef\@tempa{%
    \noexpand\suspendedtrue
    \noexpand\end{#2}%
    \def\expandafter\noexpand\csname resume.#1\endcsname{%
      \csname c@\@listctr\endcsname\the\csname c@\@listctr\endcsname%
    }%
  }%
  \@tempa%
}


\makeatother
```

Comment: I would have suggested writing out in the `.aux` file a subtotal of how many exercises are in each chapter, then adding those up in the subsequent run to get the "total total".