# Why is there no space after my new command?

Tags: macros

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands)

I defined a new command:

```
\newcommand{\quickSubstitution}{$x \in X$}
```

However, then I use the command as such

```
\quickSubstitution must hence be true.
```

I get no space after my command even though I have a space after `\quickSubstitution` and `must`. Why is that?