# Text in command gets glued to following text

Tags: spacing, macros

I made this command `\newcommand{\BR}{MyBrand\superscript{\scriptsize ™}}`, when I use it and write something like this `\BR is awesome` the ouput is:

MyBrand™is awesome

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Use `\BR{}` or `\usepackage{xspace} ... \newcommand{\BR}{MyBrand\superscript{\scriptsize ™}\xspace}`

Comment: Also have a look at [Space after LaTeX commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091).