# How to make an inline pgfplot

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

I have the following code to graph a function with a height of 2em, and in line with some text, but it gives an error.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}

\newcommand\quadratic{
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[axis lines=none,height=2em]
      \addplot[mark=none]{x^2};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
This image \quadratic is a quadratic.
\end{document}
```

---

```
Package pgfplots Error: Error: Plot width `23.1882pt' is too small.
This cannot be implemented while maintaining constant size for labels.
Sorry, label sizes are only approximate. You will need to adjust your width.
```

Which is kinda silly considering I've removed the labels. I want an output like so:

[image: expected result]

Comment: You can draw big and then put inside a `\scalebox{<scale>}{plot}`. Hiding axis lines or emptying the ticks don't mean that you skip the whole plotting mechanism (though plausible alternative).

Answer (score 16, accepted):

If you set `scale only axis`, there's no minimum height:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\newcommand\quadratic{%
  \begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[hide axis, scale only axis, height=2ex]
      \addplot[mark=none]{x^2};
    \end{axis}
  \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
This image \quadratic{} is a quadratic.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Cool! I didn't know that.

Comment: Works perfectly! Thanks for fixing the spacing too, but I don't quite get how appending `{}` added empty space, I've never seen that trick before.

Comment: @mcjohnalds45: take a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091

Comment: Irrelevant comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/170168/19356