# PGFPlots: How to draw a label at a zero of a function?

Tags: pgfplots

Is there an easy method to construct a node (and hence a label) at a zero of a function, i.e. at the intersection of the function with the `x`-axis? The examples I found were somehow too complicated, and following the KISS principle, I was wondering if there is an elementary method to achieve this.

Edit: To be a bit more precise: I would like to obtain a tick label at the zero of an arbitrary function. The zero should be calculated by the program (so if this is automation, then automation is needed).

Comment: Does need to be automated, or can it be done manually?

Comment: I'm a little confused by your comment and edit to your question :) They seem to contradict one another....

Comment: fixed this and deleted the misleading comment. Sorry for the inconvenience

Comment: possible starting point: [pgfplots: Placing node on a specific x-position](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/88404)

Comment: You should probably give Peter credit for this one.  It's only worth 15 points, but still.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Expanding on @Peter Grill 's solution, here is how to calculate the x coordinates.

[image: with ticks]

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\newlength{\len}
\newlength{\plotwidth}
\newcommand{\getvalue}[1]{\pgfkeysvalueof{/pgfplots/#1}}

%output will be given by \pgfmathresult
\newcommand{\xcoord}[1]% #1 = node name
{\pgfplotsextra{%
  \pgfextractx{\len}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfplotspointaxisxy{0}{0}}{\pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}}}%
  \pgfextractx{\plotwidth}{\pgfpointdiff{\pgfplotspointaxisxy{\getvalue{xmin}}{0}}%
  {\pgfplotspointaxisxy{\getvalue{xmax}}{0}}}%
  \pgfmathparse{\len*(\getvalue{xmax}-\getvalue{xmin})/\plotwidth}%
}}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            domain=-4:7,
            xmax=7,
        ]
        \addplot[no marks,blue,thick, name path global=My Graph] {x*x-4*x-7};
        \addplot[no marks,draw=none, name path global=x Axis] {0};
        \path[name intersections={of=My Graph and x Axis,total=\t}];

        \draw[very thin,color=gray] (intersection-1) -- +(0,-5mm) coordinate(tick1);
        \xcoord{intersection-1}%
        \node[below] at (tick1) {\pgfmathresult};

        \draw[very thin,color=gray] (intersection-2) -- +(0,-5mm) coordinate(tick2);
        \xcoord{intersection-2}%
        \node[below] at (tick2) {\pgfmathresult};
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Excellent!! You might as well provide an answer to [Convert from physical dimensions to axis cs coordinate values](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/170015/convert-from-physical-dimensions-to-axis-cs-coordinate-values). Also, I don't think you should assume that there are exactly 2 intersections and there may be 0, 1 or more than 2.

Comment: Actually, I still have a bug.  Let me work a bit more.

Comment: Okay, I fixed it.

Comment: Yep, seems to work great.

Comment: @Peter Grill - i just didn't bother with putting it in a loop.  All the work is done in \xcoord{node}.

Comment: Actually, \xcoord{} cannot be inside a loop.

Comment: Shouldn't it be easy, instead of drawing the red dots, to draw an extra tick and extra tick label? I'm relly having problem with the syntax in the \fill command. But probably I have to think about it more and look in the manuals :)

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1 - The extra ticks have to be given before starting the plot, and they normally look just like ordinary ticks.  It is easier to fake them.  BTW, \xcoord seem rather fragile: you can't use it inside a node or a path.  Also, I tried using \pgfplotsconvertunittocoordinate but it wasn't even close.

Comment: Is there some reason that values given are wrong?  Given a=1, b=-4, and c=-7, I would expect 2±√11, approx 2±3.316625

Comment: @Thurston - The values -1.31 and 5.31 are right (i just double checked).  But using \pgfplotsconvertunittocoordinate gave values orders of magnitude off.  Besides the axis coordinates and screen coordinates, pgfplot also uses coordinates where the lower left corner is (0,0) and the upper right corner is (1,1).  Or it could just be a bug.

Answer (score 20):

Here is an example of how to automatically compute the zero of the function using the `intersections` library:

[image]

### Notes:

- I don't know how to extract the `x` value of the intersection.  The solution from [Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz) can extract the coordinate, but that needs to be converted to an `axis cs` value.

### Code

```
\documentclass[border=2pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[
            axis x line=middle,
            axis y line=middle,
            domain=-4:7,
            xmax=7,
        ]
        \addplot[no marks,blue,thick, name path global=My Graph] {x*x-4*x-7};
        \addplot[no marks,draw=none, name path global=x Axis] {0};
        \fill[red,name intersections={of=My Graph and x Axis,total=\t}]
            \foreach \s in {1,...,\t}{
                (intersection-\s) circle (2pt) 
            };
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why do you need the x coordinate?  You can \draw(intersection-1) +(0,2mm) -- +(-.2mm) for a tick, or (interesection-1 |- y) to locate (x,y).

Comment: @JohnKormylo: Yes, drawing a tick is not a problem, but I thought the OP wanted to label the `x` value: `-1.32` and `5.32` for example.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. In the case I'm considering, the zero of the function is a "critical saturation". Hence, I'd like to have a tick there with an appropriate label. Is it correct, that the coordinate conversion that I'm going to need is explained in the pgfplots manual?

Comment: @Quickbeam2k1: I haven't looked, but there must be a way to convert the physical coordinate. which is easily extractable via the linked question, into the axis coordinate.  If it is helpful I can edit question to show the coordinate in points.

Answer (score 3):

Just for typing exercise with PSTricks.

```
\documentclass[pstricks,border=12pt,nomessages]{standalone}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-plot,fp}

\psset{yunit=.5}
\def\f(#1){((#1)^2-4*(#1)-7)}
\begin{document}
\begin{pspicture}[algebraic](-3,-12)(7.5,7.5)
    \psaxes[Dy=2,Dx=2]{->}(0,0)(-3,-12)(7,7)[$x$,0][$y$,90] 
    \psplot[linecolor=blue,linewidth=1pt]{-2}{6}{\f(x)}
        \FPqsolve{\xa}{\xb}{1}{-4}{-7}
        \FPeval\xa{round(xa:2)}\FPeval\xb{round(xb:2)}
    \pstInterFF[PointNameSep=17pt,PosAngle=30,PointName=\xa]{\f(x)}{0}{-2}{A}
    \pstInterFF[PointNameSep=17pt,PosAngle=150,PointName=\xb]{\f(x)}{0}{5}{B}
\end{pspicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]