# Converting unit to coordinate works for x-coordinate, but not for y-coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplots

By Jake's help I received a solution (in principle) for an "older" version of this question [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/174205/extracted-coordinates-have-wrong-value), i.e. to extract/convert units in the data to local measures.

It works for *x*, yet unexpectedly fails for the *y*-coordinate.

Why does `\pgfplotsconvertunittocoordinate` not work twice for the same point? Is there some additional code needed?

### Picture

[image]

### Data

http://pastebin.com/5AkHFZhh

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
    lmodern,
    amsmath
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{
    tikz,
    pgfplots
    }
\usetikzlibrary{
    calc
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[
height=6cm,
width=14cm,
%
scale only axis=true,
xlabel={Distance in mm},
ylabel={Voltage in volt},
]
\addplot [sharp plot, no marks, x=Wegnormiert] table [col sep=tab] {data.txt} coordinate [pos=0.4] (A) coordinate [pos=0.6] (B);
\filldraw let \p1= (A) in (\x1,\y1) circle [radius=1pt] node[pin={270:({{\pgfplotsconvertunittocoordinate{x}{\x1}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}}};{{\pgfplotsconvertunittocoordinate{y}{\y1}\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}}})}] {};
\draw (A) -| (current axis.west) coordinate (Ay) node[midway, above right=2pt, fill=white] {\(\simeq -2\)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to get you going, there are some alternatives:

There is a feature to access the coordinates of a anything around `pos`: `\pgfplotspointplotattime{0.4}` . This is probably the most simple way, although it is not quite the way one wants it to be:

```
\documentclass{standalone}

\usepackage{
    lmodern,
    amsmath
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{
    tikz,
    pgfplots
    }
\usetikzlibrary{
    calc
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[
height=6cm,
width=14cm,
%
scale only axis=true,
xlabel={Distance in mm},
ylabel={Voltage in volt},
]
\addplot [sharp plot, no marks, x=Wegnormiert] table [col sep=tab] {data.txt}
    coordinate[pos=0.4,pin={270:{%
      \pgfplotspointplotattime{0.4}%
      $(\pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]
              {\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/x}};
        \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]
            {\pgfkeysvalueof{/data point/y}})$
    }}] (A);
\filldraw let \p1= (A) in (\x1,\y1) circle [radius=1pt] ;
\draw (A) -| (current axis.west) coordinate (Ay) node[midway, above right=2pt, fill=white] {\(\simeq -2\)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Details for this approach are in section Placing Nodes on Coordinates of a Plot in the `pgfplots` manual.

Alternative solutions (which are closer to what you expect) are outline by @Jake. A similar (equivalent) solution for your plot would be to add `disabledatascaling` to the option list of the axis.

---

That said, your question is actually the feature request "This is a PGF point. Please give me the associated high level coordinate". I have taken a note on the todo list for `pgfplots`.

The implementation of this feature request will go along the suggestions of @Jake.

Sorry for causing confusion with `\pgfplotsconvertunittocoordinate`: this routine should not be part of the manual at all as it use if for internal routines (only). I will remove it from the manual and insert a suitable function once it is ready.

Comment: Ha, that is incredible–it actually is a value of 2 for *y*! That was one sharp estimate I did there. Well I find your code quite readable as well and will gladly use it, when you say `pgfplotsconvertunittocoordinate` is not intended to be used for that kind of operation.. and especially when the good code can be found in the manual. Silly me, I glanced over that relevant page (299) yesterday but didn't realize it was *the* one. Having said that, I think the feature is already implemented.

Comment: Well, accessing logical coordinates for something identified by means of `pos=0.4` _is_ implemented. But accessing logical coordinates for some node label `(A)` is not. And the current solution for `pos=0.4` feels strange: sometimes one needs to provide the argument `{0.4}` sometimes not... well, it is how it is. But I am glad you find it usable.

Answer (score 3):

This happens because PGFPlots rescales and shifts units for axes with small or large ranges. In this case, the x axis is unscaled, but the y axis is shifted and scaled. In order to get the correct values, you need to undo the transformation. The easiest way to do this is to pass the value through `\pgfplotscoordmath{<axis>}{datascaletrafo inverse to fixed}{<value>}`:

[image]

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrartcl}

\usepackage{
    lmodern,
    amsmath
}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{
    tikz,
    pgfplots
    }
\usetikzlibrary{
    calc
}

\listfiles

\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}[font=\small]
\begin{axis}[
height=6cm,
width=14cm,
%
scale only axis=true,
xlabel={Distance in mm},
ylabel={Voltage in volt},
]
\addplot [sharp plot, no marks, x=Wegnormiert] table {
0 -10
130 10
} coordinate [pos=0.4] (A) coordinate [pos=0.6] (B);
\filldraw let \p1= (A) in (\x1,\y1) circle [radius=1pt] node[pin={270:({{%
    \pgfplotsconvertunittocoordinate{x}{\x1}%
    \pgfplotscoordmath{x}{datascaletrafo inverse to fixed}{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}}};{{%
    \pgfplotsconvertunittocoordinate{y}{\y1}%
    \pgfplotscoordmath{y}{datascaletrafo inverse to fixed}{\pgfmathresult}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber[fixed,precision=1]{\pgfmathresult}}})}] {};
\draw (A) -| (current axis.west) coordinate (Ay) node[midway, above right=2pt, fill=white] {\(\simeq -2\)};
\end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{center}

\end{document}
```