# Spacing between custom command and subsequent text

Tags: spacing, macros

I have defined a custom command for the name of my project; e.g. `\newcommand{\projectname}{Gizmo}`.
When I used the command in my document, I've found that I need to place a `~` after the command in order to provide a space between the command and the text that follows.

For example in my `tex` document,

```
The \projectname is on track.
```

Produces the following `pdf` output:

```
The Gizmois on track.
```

So I have to use a tilda as follows:

```
The \projectname~is on track.
```

Which now produces the correct `pdf` output:

```
The Gizmo is on track.
```

Would someone please clarify what is going on and what is the correct (best practice) for dealing with this situation.

Comment: Use `\projectname\ is...`

Comment: There are [several approaches](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290504/89497)...no real consensus on the "best".