# Drawbacks of csname method to avoid spaces after command

Tags: spacing, macros, expansion

I had a similar problem as this one: [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands/290504#290504)

My first attempt was something like this:

```
\newcommand{\satip}{SAT\textgreater IP}
```

This leads to the known Problem, that spaces after the command are eaten up:

```
\satip is a cool Protocol. %Produces: SAT>IPis a cool Protocol.
                             space missing ^^^
```

I searched around and found the mentioned Question. The provided solutions helped a lot, but I wasn't completely happy with any of them. `\satip/` just looks a little bit strange in a latex document, I like `\satip{}` much more. It's just, if I forget to put `{}` behind the command, the space is missing in output. Therefor I'd like to get an error if I use it wrong.

Possible Solution:

```
\def\satip#{SAT\textgreater IP}
%\satip is a cool Protocol. %doesn't compile, error
```

This way the open brace is enforced, but the braces can contain something:

```
\satip{is} a cool Protocol.
```

This compiles well, but as it doesn't make any sense, I'd like it to produce an error.
My current way to handle the Problem is this:

```
\expandafter\def\csname satip{}\endcsname \relax{SAT\textgreater IP}
\def\satip#1{\csname satip{}\endcsname #1\relax}

%\satip{is} a cool Protocol. %Use of \satip{} doesn't match its definition.
%\satip is a cool Protocol. %Use of \satip{} doesn't match its definition.
\satip{} is a cool Protocol. %works
```

Now my Question:

This Macro needs a second expansion step. Could that cause any trouble? Are there other Problems? (As I haven't found this anywhere before.)

PS: Sorry for the bad title, I didn't came up with something better. Feel free to edit.

Comment: If anyone wants to play around: [https://www.overleaf.com/4337209grgmrz]

Comment: I would just use `\satip\ `, and I don't see why `\satip{is}` should produce an error with that definition.

Comment: Mmm... you can always use `\satip{} is a cool protocol` with your first definition `\newcommand*\satip{SAT\textgreater IP}`, no need to define it obscurely.

Comment: The most efficient solution is `\satip\ ` .  If you really want an error, `\def\satip/` is a reasonable way to go, and surely easier to write than `\satip{}`. And of course in the right circumstances, the `\xspace` package may be an option, though it is not always the right choice (there's a question on `comp.text.tex` about this).

Comment: @PaulGessler `\satip{ip}` doesn't produce an error, but i want it to produce an error, since this usage doesn't make any sense. (i'm not good with english, how can i say it more clearly?)

Comment: @TS it makes perfect sense: `ip` (a brace-delimited group) is typeset immediately following the expansion of macro `\satip`. Whether that is what you want is another matter, but in terms of how (La)TeX works, it's perfectly valid usage.

Comment: Ahh sorry, my english is too bad. Yes, for LaTeX is perfectly ok, but it doesn't make any sense to me in the context where it is used.

Comment: Since you are using `{}` as a conceptual delimiter for the control sequence, *any* deviation from `{}` should raise an error. `\satip{\relax}` compiles just fine. Also, you have no way of knowing if you are overwriting an existing control sequence with the name `satip` or (less likely) `satip{}` by using `\def`.

Comment: @Guho I haven't thought about `\satip{\relax}` thanks. In the final version I wanted to guard the definition with `\@ifundefined` or similar...

Comment: @TS great question! I amended the answer you linked in your question to clarify the behavior of `#{`. Might be of interest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always use

```
\newcommand*\satip{SAT\textgreater IP}
\satip{} is a cool protocol
```

I don't see the problem.

---

By the way, your last definition defines de macro with name `satip{}` (braces *included* in the macro name) to be followed by a `\relax` token. If you put the `#1` between `\endcsname` and `\relax` in the `\satip` macro it can only work if `#1` is empty (i.e., only if empty braces are given `\satip{} is...`).

---

May be this achieves what you want?

```
\newcommand*\satip[1]
 {\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax
    SAT\textgreater IP%
  \else
    \GenericError{} % <- I don't know what this argument does
       {Wrong use of \string\satip{}.} % <- short version
       {Wrong use of \string\satip. You must use \string\satip\space followed by an empyt argument `{}'.}% <- long version
  \fi}
```

Comment: I knew of the fact, that the macro `satip{}` is defined (additional to `satip`), but didn't expect any problems with this, are there any?

Comment: Reading your comment above: you want to use `\satip{} is a cool...` but you want to ensure that `{}` is empty, i.e. *not* `\satip{is} a cool...`?

Comment: YES!! (my englisch is to bad, sorry that this wasn't clear...)

Comment: `\newcommand*\satip[1]{SAT\textgreater IP\if\relax\detokenize{#1}\relax\else\PackageError{ts}{wrong use of \string\satip.}{Definitely wrong use of \string\satip{}.}\fi}` but I don't get why would you want that. In TeX a `{}` following `\satip` doesn't mean it's an argument of `\satip`.

Comment: That actually works, thanks. I haven't thought about "In TeX a `{}` following `\satip` doesn't mean it's an argument of `\satip`". That makes it obvious why `\def\satip#{...}` is ok or even better.

Answer (score 3):

I wouldn't use `{}` in the name of the auxiliary macro, but the method is sound:

```
\newcommand{\satip}[1]{\csname satip\string+\endcsname #1\relax}
\expandafter\def\csname satip\string+\endcsname\relax{%
  SAT\textgreater IP%
}
```

will trigger an error in case `\satip{x}` is used

```
! Use of \satip+ doesn't match its definition.
<argument> x
```

However `\satip ip` wouldn't. You should do *two* steps:

```
\newcommand{\satip}{}% initialize
\protected\def\satip#{\csname satip\string+\endcsname}
\expandafter\def\csname satip\string+\endcsname#1{%
  \csname satip\string+\string+\endcsname #1\relax
}
\expandafter\def\csname satip\string+\string+\endcsname\relax{%
  SAT\textgreater IP%
}
```

Now both `\satip x` and `\satip{x}` would trigger errors:

```
! Use of \satip doesn't match its definition.
l.14 \satip x

? 
! Use of \satip++ doesn't match its definition.
<argument> x

l.16 \satip{x}

?
```

Note `\protected` in front of the definition of `\satip`, so it wouldn't be expanded in “moving arguments” contexts.

An abstract version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\definestringcommand[2]{%
  \@ifdefinable#1{\@definestringcommand#1{#2}}%
}

\newcommand{\@definestringcommand}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \escapechar=\m@ne % get rid of the backslash
  % require brace
  \protected\xdef#1##{\expandafter\noexpand\csname\string#1\string+\endcsname}%
  % examine the argument
  \expandafter\xdef\csname\string#1\string+\endcsname##1{%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname\string#1\string+\string+\endcsname##1\relax
  }%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname\string#1\string+\string+\endcsname\relax{#2}%
  \endgroup
}
\makeatother

\definestringcommand{\satip}{SAT\textgreater IP}

\begin{document}

\satip is nice

\satip{x} is nice

\satip{} is nice

\end{document}
```

Whether this is useful, I leave the decision to you.

A different implementation: check for the `{`, then check for a following `}` eating up both tokens in case of success.

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\definestringcommand[2]{%
  \@ifdefinable#1{\@definestringcommand#1{#2}}%
}

\newcommand{\@definestringcommand}[2]{%
  \begingroup
  \escapechar=\m@ne % get rid of the backslash
  % require brace
  \protected\xdef#1##{%
    \expandafter\noexpand\csname\string#1\string+\endcsname
  }%
  \expandafter\gdef\csname\string#1\string+\endcsname{%
    #2%
    \afterassignment\@checkrightbrace\let\@forget= % the space counts
  }
  \endgroup
}
\newcommand{\@checkrightbrace}{%
  \@ifnextchar\egroup{\let\@forget= }{\@strcmderr\let\@forget= }%
}
\newcommand{\@strcmderr}{%
  \@latex@error{Non empty group}{The braces must contain nothing}%
}
\makeatother

\definestringcommand{\satip}{SAT\textgreater IP}

\begin{document}

\satip is nice

\satip{x} is nice

\satip{} is nice

\end{document}
```

Comment: Why should `\satip ip` produce no error? Isn't `i` the argument in this case? Here it produces an error: [https://www.overleaf.com/4337962szgjcf]

Comment: @TS Yes, it would; but not because a brace is missing. I was still thinking to the `\def\satip#` method.

Comment: ahh ok, thanks. What's the benefit of using `+` in the name  of the auxiliary macro? with `{}` the correct usage `\satip{}` shows up in the error message "Use of \satip{} ..." (at least in some way)

Comment: @TS The benefit is having a macro name that can't be ordinarily produced. The idea with `{}` is interesting, though I'd not use it. But it's your code, not mine. `;-)` I'd simply go with `\newcommand{\satip}{SAT\textgreater IP}`, to be honest.

Comment: Can the macro name `satip{}` be produced "ordinarily"? (I assume "ordinarily" means without `\csname`)

Comment: @TS If you rewrite the parser so that it treats `{}` other than TeX treats it, you mean?

Comment: @cfr No. From egreg's comment I got the impression, that using the macro name `satip+` has the benefit, that it "can't be ordinarily produced". I thought this means, that if I write `\satip+` the `+` is not part of the macro name. If I compare this to the macro name `satip{}`, I assumed it's the same, because in `\satip{}` the `{}` also isn't part of the macro name. Therefor I don't get it, whats the benefit of using `+`?

Comment: The `+` *is* part of the name @TS.

Comment: If one writes `\csname satip\string+\endcsname` the `+` is part of the name, but if I just write `\satip+`, I thought the macro name was `satip` with `+` as argument. Am I wrong?

Comment: @TS That's right

Comment: Ok, but isn't this the same with `\csname satip{}\endcsname` where `{}` is part of the macro name and `\satip{}` where `{}` is not part of the macro name?