# Odd behaviour with chemformula, hyphens, commas and periods.

Tags: chemmacros, chemformula

I'm trying to write out a formula, and I'm having trouble getting it to work in `chemmacros`

What I want is 2,2'-bpy, with a prime and a hyphen. What I get is 2.2"-"bpy, with a period and quotes around the hyphen (hyphen is used, somewhat annoyingly as I've never seen a time I'd want that, as a bond instead of a hyphen in formulas. So you have to put it in quotes. You have to add a space after the second 2, so that they don't go subscript.)

MWE, with an example of what should happen below what is happening.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{formula=chemformula, %use chemformula instead of say, mhchem
    } 

\begin{document}
\ch{(UO2)2( 2, 2 \chemprime "-" bpy)(CH3CO2)(O)(OH)}


\ch{UO2 "-" H2O2 "-" K2CO3}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[After macros spaces are ignored](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091). This is why in

```
\ch{(UO2)2( 2, 2 \chemprime "-" bpy)(CH3CO2)(O)(OH)}
```

`chemformula` sees the following pieces of input (in the order of appearance):

- `(UO2)2(` interpreted as formula
- `2,` interpreted as stoichiometric factor
- `2` interpreted as stoichiometric factor
- `\chemprime "-"` interpreted as formula
- `bpy)(CH3CO2)(O)(OH)` interpreted as formula

In stoichiometric factors decimals can be input with comma or point but the output (option `decimal-marker`) is always a point. A stoichiometric factor is followed by a space in the output (option `stoich-space`). Inside a compound `"` is not removed.

Since *2,2'-bpy* logically is more a chemical *name* than a *formula* I'd escape the whole thing – this prevents the number being typeset as subscripts, prevents the conversions of the comma and the dash:

```
\ch{(UO2)2( "2,2\chemprime-bpy" )(CH3CO2)(O)(OH)}
```

or even

```
\ch{(UO2)2( "\iupac{2,2'-bpy}" )(CH3CO2)(O)(OH)}
```

Complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{chemmacros}
\chemsetup{
  formula=chemformula, %use chemformula instead of say, mhchem
} 

\begin{document}

\ch{(UO2)2( 2, 2 \chemprime "-" bpy)(CH3CO2)(O)(OH)} \par
\ch{(UO2)2( "2,2\chemprime-bpy" )(CH3CO2)(O)(OH)} \par
\ch{(UO2)2( "\iupac{2,2'-bpy}" )(CH3CO2)(O)(OH)}

\end{document}
```

[image]