# \noindent doesn't work in macro with parameter

Tags: spacing, paragraphs

Consider the following MWE.

```
\documentclass{minimal}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand*{\mynoindent}{\noindent}
\newcommand*{\yournoindent}[1]{\noindent}

\begin{document}

\noindent
\lipsum[1]

\mynoindent
\lipsum[1]

\yournoindent{stuff}
\lipsum[1]

\end{document}
```

This outputs the following.
[image: Output]
Here are close-ups of the relevant indentations (the first two are identical, and so I only show one of those).
[image: \noindent]
[image: \yournoindent]

If you look closely, you can see that the second is indented every so slightly.  How can I go about fixing this?

(Of course, in this example, I don't actually use the parameter, but for what I want to do, I need to be able to send a parameter to a command that ends in a `\noindent`.)

Comment: you should almost never use `\noindent` in the definition of a top level latex command anyway (it is only used in one place in the latex format, in `\@hangfrom` which isn't really a latex command, just a remnant of plain tex.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle You mean like how you should almost never use `\def` in a top-level LaTeX command?  In this case, there is the LaTeX `\newcommand`.  What is the LaTeX version of `\noindent`?

Comment: No, `\newcommand` resolves to `\def` anyway so if you know what you are doing and know it is safe to omit some checks then `\def` works. But `\noindent` (as demonstrated here) almost always does the wrong thing.  if you look where indentation is suppressed eg after a section heading, latex never uses `\noindent` (and here you should probably be using the same `\@afterheading` hook to control that). Unlike `\def` where latex uses `\def` wrapped in `\newcommand` latex really doesn't use `\noindent` at all.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle What is the 'correct' way to go about doing this then?  The effect I am going for in practice is not unlike the effect with `\section`.  More specifically, I have a command `\Step` that takes a single argument and outputs "Step `<counter>`:  `<argument>`".  It then ends the paragraph, and finally ends with a `\noindent` (and now `\noindent\ignorespaces`) (it also of course increases the counter).

Comment: I'd probably define it using `\@startsection` (basically a copy of say subsubsection from article.cls but with modified formatting of the argument and number)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use

```
\newcommand*{\yournoindent}[1]{\noindent\ignorespaces}
```

which should gobble (or ignore) the space following `\yournoindent{<stuff>}`.

Comment: Thanks!  This works.  Could you explain why though?  Naively looking at the code, there doesn't seem to be any more spaces in the third case than there are in the first and second.

Comment: @JonathanGleason: The is a difference between a macro with an argument and one without. Try `\newcommand\abc}{} \newcommand{\ABC}[1]{}` and then write `This\abc that. This\ABC{stuff} that.` The former gobbles the space between `This` and `that`. The latter preserves it.

Comment: @JonathanGleason: Also see [Space after LaTeX commands](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/5764).

Comment: `\newcommand\abc}{}` is there an extra brace there?

Comment: @AFeldman: There is, and I can't edit my comments anymore. Was supposed to just be `\newcommand{\abc}{}` or `\newcommand\abc{}`, not `\newcommand\abc}{}`.

Comment: Thanks, I figured that was the case.  I only asked because of the possibility that there was something I had no clue about.