# Why is there no space after omega (and what can I do after it)

Tags: spacing, macros

I put omegas in my text as needed using a command:

```
\newcommand{\ohm}{$\Omega$ }
```

Then I needed other symbols so I included package `gensymb`. But when I do, \ohm is already defined. So I tried using the one defined in the library.  It does not add a space afterward, not sure why. My `\kohm` and `\Mohm` work fine.  I'm not sure whether I should be overriding the `\ohm` command.  What is the best approach to solve this problem?

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage{gensymb}
\newcommand{\fahren}{\degree F}
%\newcommand{\cels}{\degree C}
%\newcommand{\ohm}{$\Omega$ }
\newcommand{\kohm}{k$\Omega$ }
\newcommand{\Mohm}{M$\Omega$ }

\begin{document}
test \ohm
test \kohm
test \Mohm
I measure temperature in \fahren
\end{document}
```

I do not want to have to add braces or a backslash after the command: `\ohm{}` or `\ohm\`

The `\kohm` command works as I want it to, inserting a space afterward because it is an equation. I suppose I can define a `\ohm` command that is exactly the same as `\kohm` but then I would have to replace every one of the `\ohm` commands in multiple documents.

Comment: May be you can take a look at `siunitx`, which creates a complete interface for units.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's really your choice. If you want to use `\ohm` the way you defined it, the load the [`gensymb` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/gensymb) and redefine `\ohm`:

```
\usepackage{gensymb}
\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ohm}{$\Omega$ }}
```

The redefinition is delayed until `\AtBeginDocument`, as `gensymb` looks for the presence of [`textcomp`](http://ctan.org/pkg/textcomp) in order to define an appropriate `\ohm`.

Forcing a space after the command wouldn't always work, as you'll see when you use something like `Check out this \ohm.` For general attempts at adding spaces of commands, see [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/5764).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{gensymb}

\AtBeginDocument{\renewcommand{\ohm}{$\Omega$ }}

\newcommand{\fahren}{\degree F}
\newcommand{\kohm}{k$\Omega$ }
\newcommand{\Mohm}{M$\Omega$ }

\begin{document}

test \ohm
test \kohm
test \Mohm
I measure temperature in \fahren. test \ohm.

\end{document}
```

Comment: as much as i dislike suggesting it, `\xspace` might be appropriate here.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ~ after the ohm statement in order to force the space. It is used to ensure whatever is attached by ~ does not break to the next line so it is not always appropriate. That being said it is the quickest fix I have found.

```
Resistor value of 50~\ohm~used in...
```

Comment: Have you ever tried `50~\ohm\ used in...`? (;-)