# How to I use a command in a href

Tags: hyperref, urls

I have the following code:

```
\usepackage{hyperref}
\newcommand{\version}{0.1.2}
\href{https://example.com}{version \version{}}
```

It produces a URL like:

[version 0.1.2](http://example.com)

If I try this instead:

```
\href{https://example.com/\version{}}{version}
```

I don't get a functional URL.

Is it possible to do something like this to construct a URL with variables in it?

Comment: It looks like what's happening is that a link is being generated to `https://example.com/0.1.2{}` which is an invalid url. If I remove the `{}` at the end of your `\version{}`, then I indeed get a functional link pointing to `https://example.com/0.1.2`. That may solve your problem. (I found this out by putting `\tracingall` at the top of the file and grepping for the url. I'm leaving this as a comment rather than an answer, because I don't know enough about `href` or about macro expansion to explain what's going on.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just remove the trailing `{}` that forms part of the URL:

```
\href{https://example.com/\version}{version}
```

Appending `{}` to a macro is only needed if you which to set a regular space between a macro and a following word, as in

```
\newcommand{\arnold}{Arnold Schwarzenegger}

\arnold{} is a \ldots
```

See [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/5764).

Comment: But why doesn't it work with the `{}`? Could you explain?

Comment: (Incidentally, the top-voted answer at the question you linked to begins with "If you create a macro without arguments you should always invoke it with an empty statement after it: `\arnold{}`" – following that advice may have been what led to this question.)

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: It does work. Under both Adobe and Sumatra I get a functional URL where `{}` is replaced with `%7B%7D` by the browser (Chrome).

Comment: Well yes (though it doesn't work in OS X Preview, and of course it's a different URL from what the OP wanted so it's arguable what "work" means here), but anyway the question I meant is: why does the url become `https://example.com/0.1.2{}` rather than `https://example.com/0.1.2` with `\version{}` expanding into `0.1.2` sooner. In other words, what should the user's mental model be, to predict this and not make this mistake?

Comment: @ShreevatsaR why would you expect the `{}` to go? they are unconnected with the `\version` macro, which has no arguments, it is the same as `\href{abc{}xyz}{text}` the `{}` would be in the URL. `\version` expands to `0.1.2` so `\version{}` expands to`0.1.2{}`

Comment: @DavidCarlisle The OP seems to have expected it to go :-) I personally wouldn't expect it (or at least be sure of it), which is why I turned on tracing to make sure. I think what happens is that people see recipes like [at the linked answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands/31094#31094) and pick up rules-of-thumb like "always put `{}` after your macro ‘invocation’" without understanding what's going on and when they apply, so it may be helpful to provide that understanding instead of more rules-of-thumb. Anyway, guess this is something for the OP to ask.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle BTW, your comment is the sort of explanation I would have wished an answer to contain. (If you see the comment on the question, I left the comment before this answer was posted, and left it as a comment because I didn't consider "just remove your `{}`" to be a sufficient answer and one which would dispel the OP's confusion. Oh well.)

Comment: Thanks to all and this comment thread was very useful. I did indeed assume `\version{}` with the `{}` was mandatory.

Comment: @ShreevatsaR: URLs may contain many characters which or otherwise considered *special* in (La)TeX, like `_` or `#`, say. As such, care is taken to allow for this, which means that using content that would typically set *nothing* if used in a different context - an empty group `{}` - may actually end up in the URL.