# Let a command be a parameter marker

Tags: macros

I am trying to make a macro that defines a one-parameter macro for me (the reason is a veeeery long story). Here's my implementation.

```
\def\foo#1#2{%
\expandafter\def\csname bar#1\endcsname##1{#2}%
}

\foo{qix}{:: #1 ::}

\barqix{hi world}
```

Now the question. Using the `#1` notation is possible but unaesthetic in my application. I would like use instead an unused macro, e.g. `\PARAM` . I guess for this I should be `\let`ing `\PARAM` to `#1`, but something goes wrong if I do.

Any idea to get around this?

Comment: So you'd like `\foo{qix}{:: \PARAM ::}`? I find this much less aesthetic, besides giving a wealth of problems with space clobbering.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do that by storing the captured argument in `\PARAM`. Note that [parameterless macros gobble spaces after them](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/5764), so you'll have to be careful in what you pass to the resulting macro:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\def\foo#1#2{%
  \expandafter\def\csname bar#1\endcsname##1{\def\PARAM{##1}#2}%
}

\foo{baz}{:: \PARAM ::}

\barbaz{hi world}

\foo{bat}{:: {\PARAM} ::}

\barbat{hi world}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Well, if a call is nested…

Comment: @egreg: As in `\barbat{hi \barbat{world}}`?

Comment: For instance. If `\PARAM` is used twice, I foresee disaster.

Comment: This solution works, but as @egreg comments it might get very tricky if nested, which is precisely what I intended to do...

Comment: @Jaeya: It would be great if you can show examples of your use cases (which includes nesting).

Comment: I haven't yet writen one, but long story short: I am making an object-oriented engine and `\PARAM` is intended to be a sort of `this` in C++. When calling a destructor e.g. in a linked list, subsequent destructor calls will be issued.

Comment: I am actually unsure about how it will behave right now. I'll play with the idea and see if it would work. Thanks!

Comment: @Jaeya: You're better-suited to know what will work in your environment than me. You have two answers. If mine doesn't suit your needs, then try [egreg's answer](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/355576/5764). If that doesn't work, provide more information.

Answer (score 4):

Usually people have the opposite problem. `;-)`

```
\def\PARAM{##1}
\def\foo#1#2{%
  \expandafter\edef\csname bar#1\endcsname##1{#2}%
}

\foo{qix}{:: \PARAM\space ::}

\barqix{hi world}

\bye
```

You have to use `\edef`, with all the connected problems, because TeX does no interpretation of the replacement text in a `\def`.

Otherwise, you'd have to do a lengthy scanning of the replacement text, substituting `\PARAM` with `##1`; if it appears in a group…

Besides, I find

```
\foo{qix}{:: #1 ::}
```

much less clumsy.

Just for fun, with `expl3` and `l3regex`:

```
\input expl3-generic

\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Npn \foo #1 #2
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l_tmpa_tl { #2 }
  \regex_replace_all:nnN { PARAM } { \cP\#1 } \l_tmpa_tl
  \cs_set:NV \temp:n \l_tmpa_tl
  \cs_set_eq:cN {bar#1} \temp:n
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \cs_set:Nn { NV }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\foo{qix}{:: PARAM ::}

\barqix{hi world}

\bye
```