# How to insert space in the short title and slide number in the footline of beamer?

Tags: beamer, header-footer

I am using Warsaw theme. There is no space in the short title and slide number in the footline of my beamer presentation.

This is my MWE:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Warsaw}}
%% preamble
\title[]{\sc}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.24 \paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.01cm plus1fill,rightskip=.05cm]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.76\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.05cm,rightskip=.15cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle
        \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber \ \hspace*{2ex} 
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hello World!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: The `\title[]{\sc}` doesn't look complete...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Commands that just print a text normally make the following space(s)
>   disappear (see [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091) for example).

In order to prevent this you can use **(1)** `\command{}` **(2)** `\command\` (space after `\`) or **(3)** use the `xspace` package (if you create your own commands). The list is not complete I guess.

### Short Solution

```
\insertshorttitle{}
```

### Complete Code

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\mode<presentation>{\usetheme{Warsaw}}
%% preamble
\title[Short Title]{Long Title}

\makeatletter
\setbeamertemplate{footline}{%
\leavevmode%
\hbox{\begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.24 \paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.01cm plus1fill,rightskip=.05cm]{author in head/foot}%
            \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshortauthor
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.76\paperwidth,ht=2.5ex,dp=1.125ex,leftskip=.05cm,rightskip=.15cm plus1fil]{title in head/foot}%
        \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertshorttitle{}
        \insertframenumber{} / \inserttotalframenumber \ \hspace*{2ex} 
    \end{beamercolorbox}}%
    \vskip0pt%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
Hello World!
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

### Output

[image]

Comment: Great! It helps