# Should I use `\ ` or `{}` after custom commands?

Tags: spacing, macros

I often use custom commands or macro as we all do. But I'm not sure what to do about the space following the command. I've sometimes done `\mycommand\` and sometimes I've done `\mycommand{}`. I'm not sure which is better or more correct. Perhaps there's an even better way to do this. **Can someone please describe what is the "best" way to do this?**

Comment: either works in text mode (don't use either in math), I'm sure this is a duplicate, I'll find a link

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands

Comment: This is subtely different from [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands?noredirect=1&lq=1) question. (I hadn't seen that question/answer when I posted mine.) I'm simply asking which option is better. It seems from @DavidCarlisle's comment, that neither is better than another.

Comment: For me the  `\ ` is better in the sense that text is a bit more human readable \in\ \this\ \way\ than \in{} \this{} \way{}. Moreover, reading  some as \LaTeX{} you will spend some milliseconds  checking if that is control sequence with a missing mandatory argument or only a end of macro.