# Numbers immediately after operator subscripted in mhchem environment

Tags: formatting, subscripts, mhchem

The following is the output of this MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\ce{a = 2 \times 3}\\
\ce{a = 2 \div 3}\\
\ce{a = 2 \times b}\\
\ce{a = 2 \div b}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Note how the character is subscripted only when the character after theoperator is a number.

How would I prevent the number from being subscripted?

Comment: Erh, what exactly are you trying to do here? `\ce` has a very specific use and a very specific input syntax

Comment: @daleif I'm showing a few stoichiometric calculations. Would you suggest me end the `\ce` before inputting the numbers?

Comment: I'm just curious what this has to do with mhchem

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure why you're using `\ce` for this: I see no reason for a and b being upright.

You can embed math mode in `\ce`:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\ce{a = $2 \times 3$}\\
\ce{a = $2 \div 3$}\\
\ce{a = $2 \times \ce{b}$}\\
\ce{a = $2 \div \ce{b}$}

\end{document}
```

On the other hand if the calculations are inside `\ce` material, I guess

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\ce{$a = 2 \times 3$}\\
\ce{$a = 2 \div 3$}\\
\ce{$a = 2 \times b$}\\
\ce{$a = 2 \div b$}

\end{document}
```

is what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks, using `$$` within `\ce` was what I was looking for.

Comment: Why do you use `\ce` at all? Simply write `$a = 2 \times 3$`.

Comment: @mhchem I guess that this is just a short example.

Answer (score 2):

Simply preventing the operators from gobbling the space after them by providing an empty argument fixes the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\begin{document}

\ce{a = 2 \times{} 3}\\
\ce{a = 2 \div{} 3}\\
\ce{a = 2 \times b}\\
\ce{a = 2 \div b}

\end{document}
```

See also: [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands)