# Astrophysical notation : typeset HI

Tags: formatting, typography

What would the best way to typeset HI to designate molecular gas as in [the title of this article](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1608.02601.pdf), with a capital `H` and a slightly smaller numeral `I` ? I am using the `scrbook` class.

I tried to define

```
\newcommand{\HI}{H {\uppercase{\romannumeral 1}} }
```

but this results in `H i`, with a lowercase `i`.

I also tried

```
\newcommand*{\HI}{\textsc{Hi}}
```

but this doesn't behave properly when I use it in `\section{}`, resulting in "H i" rather than "H I".

I also haven't found anything like this in `chemmacros`, which is more geared towards chemists.

---

This is a standard way of writing molecules in astrophysics, so I'm surprised there isn't a package that does this easily.

Comment: it's a tex generated file on arxiv, can't you just download the tex source and see, there is no need to use `\uppercase` and `\romannumeral` they would just generate a normal I anyway so you could simply use HI

Comment: perhaps `\textsc{Hi}`

Comment: I would not recommand the way it seems in this article... The distance between `H` and `I` makes it difficult in reading as one "thing" and possibly the author would try to use another way of defining a command in future edition of this article. @DavidCarlisle's above comment would give a better result I suppose.

Comment: The article you linked to uses `H\,{\footnotesize I}` - however I don't think this is the best way to go (you can download the tex source of the article from https://arxiv.org/format/1608.02601)

Comment: Personally I would use the `\ion` macro from the "Astronomy & Astrophysics" journal class: https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/standard30/aa.cls

Comment: @user36296 I would rather not change my document class just for the sake of two characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to do it is the way it is implemented by the [Astronomy & Astrophysics class](https://fits.gsfc.nasa.gov/standard30/aa.cls).

Add this declaration to the header :

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ion}[2]{%
\relax\ifmmode
\ifx\testbx\f@series
{\mathbf{#1\,\mathsc{#2}}}\else
{\mathrm{#1\,\mathsc{#2}}}\fi
\else\textup{#1\,{\mdseries\textsc{#2}}}%
\fi}
```

Then in the body of the document, use

```
\ion{H}{I}
```

Answer (score 8):

Use the size of subscripts linked to the current font size.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\makeatletter
\DeclareRobustCommand{\HI}{%
  \mbox{H\check@mathfonts\fontsize\sf@size\z@\selectfont I}%
}
\makeatother

\textheight=3cm % just to shorten the image

\begin{document}

\section{About \HI}

Here we talk about \HI.\footnote{Yes, about \HI.}

\end{document}
```

[image]

The kernel command `\check@mathfonts` computes `\sf@size` and `\ssf@size` starting from the current font size, either with the parameters stored with `\DeclareMathSizes` or with a heuristic otherwise.

Comment: The spacing is off when HI is in the middle of a sentence. `\HI is cool` ends up in the document as `HIis cool`.

Comment: @usernumber That's a well known fact; just add `{}` at the end: `\HI{}`. It is discussed in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/4427, but adding `{}` is the most effective way, notwithstanding what others suggest.

Answer (score 4):

Adjust `1.2ex` to suit.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\HI{H\protect\scaleto{$I$}{1.2ex}}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{This is \HI}

And in text: \HI{} and \LARGE \HI
\end{document}
```

[image]

Because `scalerel` operates, by default, in math mode, the `$I$` is actually  an escape *out of* math mode.  If that is too confusing, you could always just operate in math mode as: `\newcommand\HI{H\protect\scaleto{\textrm{I}}{1.2ex}}`

---

If you wanted a version without packages, you could do this, but it requires a separate macro for bold style:

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand\HI{$\textrm{H}\scriptstyle\mathrm{I}$}
\newcommand\HIbold{$\textbf{H}\scriptstyle\mathbf{I}$}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents

\section{This is \HIbold}

And in text: \HI{} and \LARGE \HI
\end{document}
```

[image]