# Cannot use \tex inside of \title{...}

Tags: pdftex, titles

I cannot use `\tex` inside the `\title{...}` since it fails on the `\maketitle` command. When I remove the `\tex`, the file is built correctly.

```
\begin{titlepage}
     \title{
           \normalfont
           \LARGE University name \\[25pt]
           \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} \\[0.4cm]
           \huge Semestral work XXX \\
           \rule{\linewidth}{1pt} \\[0.6cm]
           \Large Rewritten in the \tex typesetting system \\[0.5cm]  % probable cause %
      }
      \author{Nikolas Charalambidis}
      \date{\normalsize{7. 5. 2019}}
      \maketitle                                                      % failing %
      \thispagestyle{empty}
\end{titlepage}
```

The error is (I use TexMaker):

> Undefined control sequence.@title ...\[0.6cm] \Large Rewritten in the \textypesetting system \[0.5cm] \maketitle

Comment: One very very important thing, you have two possibilities: either using `\title{stuff}` and `\maketitle` to get the predefined title page; or use `titlepage` to define a title page of your own. Do not mix them up.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

(La)TeX control sequences are case-sensitive, for example `\Sigma` is different from `\sigma`. The command `\tex` is not defined yet. You need `\TeX`.

In your document, `\TeX` is followed by a space. The compiler ignores this. To add the space, you may want to read [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/156344). Personally I prefer `the \TeX\ typesetting` to `the \TeX{} typesetting`.

Note that TeX is not LaTeX. You may want to write `\LaTeX` there, because your document is written in LaTeX, not TeX. `\LaTeXe`, to produce "LaTeX 2e", fits even better.