# Space after new command is lost

Tags: macros

I found something really strange when using `newcommand` in latex. I wrap two pieces of text that are often show up in my article, which are,

```latex
\newcommand{\etal}{et al.}
\newcommand{\stra}{$\mathcal{S}_A$}
```

where the first is the abbreviation and the other is a symbol. However, when I use these two macro definion and type the following

```
Sentence 1: Liu \etal \cite{liu2019} did something.
Sentence 2: Liu \etal did somthing.
Sentence 3: Liu add \stra to this process.
```

the results are

Sentence 1: Liu et al. [1] did something.

Sentence 2: Liu et al.did something.

Sentence 3: Liu add $\mathcal{S}_A$to this process.

As you can tell, the blank after commands in the last two sentences are lost, but the space in the first sentence still exists. I am wondering how can I solve this problem.

BTW, It is not a good practice to put an extra space in the command.

Comment: Especially https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/290504/38080 is worth reading, it is a masterwork on the "space after command" subject :-)

Comment: The space appears in the first case possibly because you’re using the `cite` package.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Spaces after commands that are made of letters are ignored. This allows you to type, e.g., `\AE sop` to get Æsop since munging the letters together would make LaTeX think that you were entering a command `\AEsop` and give you an undefined control sequence error.

For your examples, you need to add `\`  to the end of the command to let LaTeX know that you do want a space there. So your sentences would be:

```
Sentence 1: Liu \etal\ \cite{liu2019} did something.
Sentence 2: Liu \etal\ did somthing.
Sentence 3: Liu add \stra\ to this process.
```

Comment: @Hosek Thanks, the problem is solved. So, in the first sentence, the space is kept because there is another command follow behind?

Comment: @Yuejiang_Li spaces get ignored after an alphabetic command regardless of what follows.