# Command to change a string on the whole document

Tags: macros, punctuation, strings

I was wondering if it was possible to use a variable within the document to quickly change a string. For example in my cover letter I want to insert the name of a different company but without changing the name manually.

So far I have used the command

```
\newcommand{\companyname}{Google }

Hi \companyname I want to ....
By \companyname, see you.
```

This method however causes problems with the text. It does not respect the space between the words that follow the command.

Result:

> Hi GoogleI want to .... By Google, see you.

I thought about adding a space to the command but if I did this it would cause an extra space to the punctuation which does not suffer this effect.

Comment: See the Arnold Schwarzenegger question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/134574.  Use `Hi \companyname{} I want to` or `Hi \companyname\ I want to`

Comment: Heve a look at `xspace` and write `\newcommand{\companyname}{NoGoogle\xspace}`

Answer (score 1):

You can define the `\companyname` with a separator. For example:

```
\def\companyname/{Google}

Hi \companyname/ I want to ....
By \companyname/, see you.
```

If you forget the declared separator, for example `By \companyname, see you` then the error

```
Use of \companyname doesn't match its definition.
```

is printed.