# Why is the spacing of \ensuremath different?

Tags: macros, spacing

If `\newcommand{\ensuremath{something}}` expands to

```tex
\ifmmode
 something
\else
 $something$
\fi
```

why is the spacing of

```tex
\newcommand{\x}{x_\textsc{y}} 
\newcommand{\y}{\ensuremath{x_\textsc{y}}}
```

different?

```tex
Why is the spacing $\x$ different?\\
Why is the spacing \y different?
```

[image: spacing]

Comment: What happens with your code without `\textsc`?

Comment: Maybe you want `x_{\mathrm{Y}}` instead?!

Comment: Note you should not rely on `_\text.. ` always use braces. It might work here and now, but noone has promised that it will keep working. The braced `_{...} ` always will.

Comment: The space after `\y` is a command terminator and is removed.

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with `\ensuremath`. It's simply because TeX swallows spaces after control sequences. In the line with `$\x$` the math mode helps you avoid this effect. In `spacing \y different` the space is swallowed. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/31091/35864

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If `\ensuremath` were defined as

```
\newcommand{\ensuremath}[1]{%
   \ifmmode
      #1
   \else
      $#1$   %<--- space here!
   \fi
}
```

like you seem to believe, then your expectation would be correct: when defining

```
\newcommand{\foo}{\ensuremath{foo}}
```

and using `\foo` in text mode, the usual TeX rules would gobble the space after `\foo` but the space would be introduced by the (supposed) definition of `\ensuremath`.

The fact is, `\ensuremath` is not defined that way:

```
\DeclareRobustCommand{\ensuremath}{%
  \ifmmode
    \expandafter\@firstofone
  \else
    \expandafter\@ensuredmath
  \fi}
\long\def\@ensuredmath#1{$\relax#1$}
```

and the expansion doesn't introduce any space.

(Question to the audience: why `\long`?)

Comment: With `\long` the error messages are better, in case one has `\par` in the argument of `\ensuremath`.

Comment: @egreg Uhm, with `\long` the error is `missing $ inserted`, without `\long` it's `paragraph ended before \@ensuredmath was complete`. I can't say the former is clearer. But it was just curiosity, I would never use `\ensuremath` to begin with `:-)`

Comment: @egreg:
Why the `\relax` in the definition `\long\def\@ensuredmath#1{$\relax#1$}`?

Comment: @rlsx Without the `\relax`, if `#1` is empty we have `$$`, which starts 'raw' TeX display math mode: that's almost certainly not what we want.

Comment: @rlsx Adding to Joseph's comment, without `\relax` a wrong input such as `\ensuremath{$x$}` (in text mode) would pass without errors.

Answer (score -1):

The previous answers make abundantly clear why, with your definition:
`*` `\newcommand{\y}{\ensuremath{x_\textsc{y}}}`
`\y` removes the following space.
As a workaround, you may consider using the package `xspace`, and (re)defining `\y`:
`*` `\newcommand{\y}{\ensuremath{x_\textsc{y}}\xspace}`
If you follow this route, look at the customization afforded by `\xspaceaddexceptions` in that package.

Comment: Using `\xspace` is not recommended. Also `x_\textsc{y}` works by accident and should be `x_{\textsc{y}}`, but probably better is `x_{\textup{\textsc{y}}}`. I find no reason to use `\ensuremath` for this case, as `$\y$` is much clearer.

Comment: Why is using `xspace` not recommended? (Otherwise, I wasn't trying the improve the `TeX`syntax of the original question.)

Comment: There are several corner cases it does not catch, and thus users have to keep this in might every time they use the macro. As egreg mentiones $\y$ is cleaner and give a proper visual separation between math and text at the source level.