# Macros and spacing

Tags: macros, spacing

Since an e with an acute accent is a pain to type, I have a macro for the name Bézier:

```
\def\Bez{B\'{e}zier}
```

I swear this used to work fine, but today I tried typing

```
The so-called \Bez curve is not really based on \Bez's original ideas.
```

And the output I got was

[image]

What happened to the space before the word "curve"?

If I add a space to my macro definition, then "Bezier curve" comes out right, but "Bezier's work" get's an extra space. What should I do?

Comment: I just found this: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands. So, unless there have been some improvements since 2009, no need to answer.

Comment: Use either `\Bez\ ` or `\Bez{}` to get a space.

Comment: LaTeX can process UTF-8 input. `Bézier` is fine.

Comment: @frougon. It might be fine for LaTeX, but it's not fine for me because Bézier is difficult to type (unless you know some trick that I don't).

Comment: @bubba My keyboard has an `é` key. Other possibilities would be input methods in Emacs and the Compose key in X11.

Comment: I'm not going to buy a French keyboard that has an é key   :-)

Comment: Here's a trick: Copy and paste the name from some external pdf file that contains the name `Bézier` into your tex document.

Comment: @Mico. Yes, that's what I often do. I thought a macro would make life easier. Maybe not.

Comment: Yes, correct duplicate. If you read carefully there are two "automatic" solutions there, with limitations.

Comment: If you're on Linux with an us keyboard, chose the us-int-altgr keyboard layout and is as simple as pressing the altgr key and ` and the the letter you want to accent. If you're on windows, https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose makes the keyboard bearable.

Comment: @bubba On other topic: In Linux, most desktops [have access to other characters](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/531023/233565) when you press `ALT + <SPEC.KEY>` followed by a letter e.g. `e` after releasing `ALT`, where `SPEC.KEY` is `;`, `'`, `#`, `[`, `]`, `,`, `.`, `/` (those are on the right-hand side of regular letters on my keyboard). For instance `ALT+[` followed by `e` gives me `ë` whereas `ALT+;` followed by `e` gives me `é`. Hope that helps.

Comment: @Rmano (and Celdor) :  Thanks, but I don't use Linux.

Comment: @bubba wincompose is a windows 10/11 app, it works nicely. It's also useful for adding emoj wherever you like .

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the best solution is to keep typing "\Bez" and then globally replace "\Bez" by "Bézier". Anyway, that's what I did.