# define \"{e} with a space

Tags: letters, letterspacing

I often use the letter "ë". I shortly define it in LaTeX as `\newcommand{\e}{\"{e}}`. However, frequently a space is needed right after the letter and I put `\;` right after the `\e`. I wanted to define it as a new command: `\newcommand{\e_}{\"{e} \;}`, but LaTeX gives an error after I run the program.

Is there any finer solution how I can define "ë " with a unique command?

Comment: The proper solution is to use `\e{}`, but why aren't you just writing ë directly? These shortcuts should not be necessary these days.

Comment: is `\e` really easier than `\"e` or `ë` neither of which have a problem with following space? Why do you need `\e` ?

Comment: I need a shortcut instead of typing alt+0235 all the time.

Comment: `\"e` is only three characters

Comment: In which system? You can use compose keys almost in everyone --- in Linux is just a matter of enabling it (search for your distribution), in Windows I suggest using https://github.com/samhocevar/wincompose --- I just type compose,",e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, it's 2022 and Unicode rules... . Why not:

```latex
\documentclass[12pt,]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\begin{document}

Without spaces, an embëddëd ë (now with space). Also Ë, clearly.

\end{document}
```

[image: ë galore...]

If the problem is typing the symbol, I suggest you google for "Compose Key".

If you insist on having a macro here, look at [Space after LaTeX commands](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/31091/space-after-latex-commands)

Answer (score 5):

According to Wikipedia, `ë` and `Ë` are available in several input encodings and a query to the input encoding support files in the LaTeX distribution reveals that they are defined in

```
ansinew
applemac
cp1250
cp1252
cp437
cp437de
cp850
cp852
cp858
cp865
decmulti
latin1
latin2
latin3
latin4
latin5
latin9
latin10
next
utf8
```

So chances are high that you can type directly `ë` and `Ë` in your typescript and you don't need special commands.

Besides, `\"e` is not much longer than `\e` and is much clearer input (if you don't want or can't input the characters themselves).

If you want to live dangerously, load `xspace` and define

```
\newcommand{\e}{\"e\xspace}
```

but this should be avoided.

Remember to use also

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
```

so you get the precomposed character in output.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't say what error you are getting. But it seems like the problem you have is that when you write `\newcommand{\e_}{\"{e} \;}` you are using the underscore, and TeX expects to see underscores in math mode.

If instead I try `\newcommand{\ee}{\"{e} \;}`, or any other name without underscore, it seems to work without issue.

On a separate note, I cannot say about other systems, but in Windows the United States International keyboard (and others, too) let you input ë by typing `"e`.